# Should questions asking for illegal content be deleted?

Tags: support, declined-flags

Today I reviewed the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958579/lifi-time-jformdesigner-license-file-please

I decided to both close the question and also flag it for moderator attention with the following comment:

> This question is asking for illegal content. Please delete it.

My request was declined with the following comment:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
>   content that requires their intervention

I still believe this question *should* be deleted and I also thought, that deleting questions requires moderator intervention.

So my question is: Should questions asking for illegal content be deleted? If yes, how should we handle such questions when reviewing?

Comment: Moderators routinely avoid enforcing the legal contract of a business that is not associated in any way with SE.  Just extinguish with fire yourself.

Comment: What's "illegal content"?

Comment: @tmyklebu In a broader sense any content that is not legal to be published on the internet as provided by the laws of your country. More specifically all content that does not comply to this sites terms of service.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Section 4 (Restrictions) of SE's Terms of Service reads:

> Use of the Network or Services to violate the security of any computer network, crack passwords or security encryption codes, transfer or store illegal material including that are deemed threatening or obscene, or engage in any kind of illegal activity is expressly prohibited.

This is clearly a violation of that particular term.  As [Martijn has already mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283571/1159478), by the time this flag came up for a moderator it didn't really require any further action on their part; the post had already been handled (although I probably would have preferred to see it marked helpful even if they didn't need to do anything in this case).  If you come across any similar content in the future, you should still flag it if the community has not already dealt with the content.

Answer (score 8):

The question is off-topic for Stack Overflow (it is not a programming question) and has already been closed. With downvotes, it'll also be *automatically* deleted soon enough. If it wasn't closed at the time you found it, all you needed to do was to vote to close it. Personally I'd have down-voted it too.

Because it is now closed, no-one can post an answer to the question either, so the OP will not get what they are seeking here on Stack Overflow.

There is no need to force deletion in this case. No moderator intervention is required here and the flag was declined correctly. Save your flags for stuff that only moderators can handle.

Comment: `Because it is already closed, no-one can post an answer to the question either`. Yes, but it was not closed, when I reviewed it...

Comment: @Balder: yet the community managed to close the post as off-topic just fine. Did you vote to close it at the time?

Comment: I decided to also close it after I saw a few others adding close votes - to increase the close count

Comment: `With downvotes, it'll also be automatically deleted soon enough` I didn't know this though - good to know for the future.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Won't automatic deletion take 9 days? I'm guessing that the OP of the closed question is not really worrying about rep but about getting an answer, which they could get through comments. Deletion would prevent this. So I voted for deletion even if the system will take care of it.

Comment: @Louis: sure, but deletion can be taken care of by 10k+ users here too. It is a crap question and is worthy of delete votes. But it is not a problem that requires moderator intervention.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was not arguing that a moderator should be involved.

Comment: @MartijnPieters 10Kers can vote delete only 2 days after it's closed

Comment: @gnat: 20k+ can vote sooner than that. I meant that the community is equipped to delete it too, I didn't state a timeline. If the question actually attracts comments that make the situation worse, *then* a flag might be warranted.

Comment: I encountered a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515869/how-to-reactivate-your-adword-account-if-banned) like that recently. The question is off-topic anyway (because it's not about programming and it [doesn't contain an actual question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)), but the main issue with it from my perspective is that what the OP is asking for is manifestly unethical (and possibly illegal). Should that have been flagged for moderator attention (or just downvote and vote to close)?

Comment: @EJoshuaS: the problem is that moderators are not in a position to judge what is illegal and what is not. Most such posts don't survive for more than 30 minutes anyway, the community is rather effective at shutting that kind of post down.