# Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?

Tags: discussion, faq, asking-questions, question-quality

To an asker, their question seems pretty good.  They've explained the context of their project, there's a detailed list of what they want to accomplish, and they've shown what they have tried / their work so far.

The problem is clear, and they need help accomplishing the tasks. They ask "can someone help me?"

Why do questions like these receive downvotes and close votes?
In the comments, people say that they haven't asked a question when they clearly have.

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: Note that this is intended to apply to pretty much any "requirements only" question

Comment: Good post. The only questions that this will be troublesome for are those that are posed by students tasked with a seemingly stupid programming assignment (e.g. "write a query to join two tables without using any join operator") - where the answer inevitably boils down to, "ask your teacher what they were thinking".

Comment: @sloth: Some call it polite. Others call it reticent and infuriating waffling. In either case, it's regarded as inappropriate fluff here.

Comment: I believe the question "Can someone help me?" is more of an implicit question resulting from a previous issue. While I believe this question to be good, most of the time it can easily be replaced by an explicit question stating the causing problem. Like when I'd say "x doesn't work. ... Can someone help me?", it better be phrased "Why doesn't x work?".

Comment: Related: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274) and [Open Letter to Students with Homework Assignments](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: Referenced in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7v0yvdkIHg&t=3m40s) (at 03 min 40 secs).

Comment: `Please see: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)`

Comment: Similar (MSE): *[Should we forbid “please help me” titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145477/)*

Answer (score 669, accepted):

Stack Overflow is a ***question & answer*** site. You may think that you have asked a reasonable, answerable question, but a question like "Can someone help me"? really doesn't qualify.

First, a bit of background: The purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a knowledge repository of solutions to programming problems. Its [mantra](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/09/16/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/) is "Make the Internet a better place". That means that a primary characteristic of a good question is that **it is likely to be searched by someone else**. "Will you help me do X?" doesn't do that. More than likely, *no one* will ever be trying to do, and searching for, the exact same thing as you in exactly the same way. On the other hand, questions like: "How do I convert a string to a number?" *are* searched very often.

Second, for the sake of argument, suppose we didn't care whether the question is useful to someone else (we do), that we are only here for *you* (we aren't). A request for help is still **impossible to answer**. Imagine what an answer might look like. It would essentially need to be the entire code base. We can appreciate that you only want "help", but with the question you've asked, we *can't provide it*. By contrast, something like "How do I convert a string to a number?" has a clear definable answer (or even multiple answers).

So, **help us help you**. When you write a question, make sure to actually *ask a question*. Answerable questions don't ask how to implement a feature, they ask how to accomplish a programming task (among other things).

There's a catch here, that asking a good question will nearly always require you to know enough to know what you don't know. If you aren't there yet, start by breaking down the problem/feature into as many small steps as you can, and ask about the ones you don't understand and can't answer by doing your own research. Although, [it helps to mention the context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

So in summary:

- Ask *one* question per post.
- Make sure it is clear *what you want to know*. Is the question about fixing existing code, or is it about figuring out the next part of the code? Either way, what specifically do you need to understand in order to solve the problem?
- Ask a specific programming question, not how to implement an entire project or feature.
- If you don't know the programming question to ask, at least break it down into as small a piece as possible, and still make it about programming, not the feature.

  - If you are trying to figure out how to do something, then think about what things need to happen and in what order, figure out what you can and can't do already, and focus on a step that causes a problem.
  - If you are trying to fix a problem in code, then try to check what each part of the code does separately, figure out what part is doing something wrong, and ask about that with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
- Wait for the reaction you get and *think* about it *before* asking the next question you may have. It might already be obsolete or just change radically.

The good news is, *you are trying to learn*. So work on the question, edit it into something answerable, or at least make sure your next question is a good one. We'll be glad to help!

Comment: The problem with "breaking down the problem/feature into as many small steps as you can, and ask about the ones you don't understand" is when they've broken the problem down into the "easy step" and the "impossible step" and are asking for help with the impossible step without letting us know what the overall problem is.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes, context is often lacking; however from the point of view of the asker I am afraid the "impossible step" brings up another challenge: they might not even see how to break it down further even if it is big. In this case, there is nothing we can do for them.

Comment: as well, *Can you help* and *is this even possible* do not make clear **what** "you" want help with.  Often there can be several things wrong, questionable or ill conceived.  The answerer is left to guess which part vexxes "you" the most or post an unduly long answer to address all the issues in your question.

Comment: As a "solo" developer that used to work in a large company, one of the parts I truly miss is the opportunity to discuss different technical approaches to meeting requirements.  It would be great to me if SE provided a place to have these kinds of discussions.

Comment: @TimothyVogel Most SO chat rooms are open to these kinds of discussions.

Comment: OMG ... SO has chat rooms!!!!  I will definitely check them out!  You might want to add that to your answer as I have been using SO for a couple of years and didn't know about them.

Comment: @TimothyVogel http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ I'll think about adding it to my answer, but I think it distracts from the main point at the moment.

Comment: @TimothyVogel Unless I'm mistaken about your meaning, [programmers.se] sounds like the perfect place for those kinds of questions. (Though if you want to have a discussion, not ask a question, the chat is definitely the place for that.)

Comment: While I understand (and agree) with what you say, I feel like this is unlikely to be either enlightening or convincing to the sort of user who asks the above meta question. I feel like I only get it because I already understood what you were going to say before you said it.

Comment: "_Answerable questions don't ask how to implement a feature, they ask how to accomplish a programming task_" - Very well said

Comment: "Ask a programming question, not how to implement something". Asking how to implement isn't a bad thing in my opinion, but the result should be pseudo code.

Comment: @KRyan That is entirely possible, if you have any suggestions on how to make it clearer, I'm certainly open to them.

Comment: @ShellFish "How do I implement a media player" is still going to be an overly-large amount of pseudo code, assuming such a thing is possible.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes I agree but everything has to be placed into context. My point is that this type of question doesn't automatically imply it to be a poor one.

Comment: @ShellFish True. To a certain extent, I'm assuming that a new user was sent here because it *was* a poor one

Comment: @Ajedi32 you are _very_ wrong, see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260) at Programmers meta. **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)**

Comment: @gnat I'm very much aware of both of those posts. If you _read_ my comment again, you'll notice that I said "those kinds of **questions**", not "those kinds of discussions", and pointed out that if you want to "have a discussion" then the chat is the place for that. If you want to ask a question though about "different technical approaches to meeting requirements", that sounds spot-on for [programmers.se], does it not? [The second highest voted question on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/) actually fits that description.

Comment: It reminds me of a question (still not closed) where someone asked for what's a 1,000+ LOC solution by specifically saying he does not want the generic (existing) open source solution. Some people think this site is elance4free.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Although some context is essential, it should only be described broadly (_I am trying to implement a media player using the Windows Media Player object model_) without all the important details of the "impossible step" (_The Play method isn't doing anything. Here is the code I am using to call the method_).

Comment: "Ask as small a question as possible" is dubious advice: it often leads to an XY problem, where the asker dutifully breaks the problem down into smaller problems *very badly*, and then asks about one of the sub-problems that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @amalloy I agree, you have to include the context. My point is to try and get past "implement this" to "how do I do this specific thing" I'm happy to word it differently if you have a suggestion.

Comment: Can you write a similar post for "is *x* possible?" type questions? It seems like that's a similar class of "unanswerable" questions (because it's totally unclear what they're asking beyond "yes" or "no") and it seems like it would be worth having a canonical answer for this type of question.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I can certainly try. Feel free to do so yourself as well, borrowing from this wherever you feel is appropriate :)

Comment: @EJoshuaS I always took "is x possible?" as synonym for "Is x possible and if so how to do it?" because if someone asks if something is possible (except in math) he/she usually wants to know right after a yes a way how do achieve it.

Comment: @Trilarion This is, of course, true. But such questions are nearly universally too broad.

Answer (score 61):

I've always seen the kind of question you're describing here as evidence that the asker hasn't really thought through the question much themselves (or, at a minimum, they didn't take time to clarify which part of the task they are struggling with). These questions will rarely describe anything concrete that the OP actually tried themselves, and when they do it'll often be in the form of "I tried *x* but [it didn't work/there was an error/insert some other vague problem statement here]".

In the vast majority of cases, it seems like "please help me" evaluates to "gimme teh codez"/"please write this for me." Even if the asker doesn't really *mean* to ask a "gimme teh codez" question, the fact that their only "question" is "please help me" *makes* it a "gimme teh codez" question because it's unclear what part of the task they need help with.

With that said, I do agree that the lack of a clear problem statement or clear question dramatically diminishes the question's potential usefulness to future readers. Personally, when I search Stack Overflow for something, I'm almost always looking for a solution to a specific problem (rather than general information about a type of problem; that's what books and tutorials are for).

Answer (score 60):

"Can you help me?" may be indicative of an unanswerable question, but **it is not necessarily so**.

People often seem to be blinded by the "ask an (actual) question" mentality and downvote and close perfectly appropriate questions that only have some less-than-ideal phrasing.

In many cases, it's trivial to convert a "Can you help me?" question into an "actual" question (whether that question would be appropriate is a different issue).

Taking your example:

> I'm trying to convert a string to a number. Can anyone help me?

versus

> How do I convert a string to a number?

The asker appears to want exactly the same thing in each case, the phrasing is just a little different.

Even if there isn't such an easy fix, it's often easy to see what the asker wants and add an "actual" question (although not necessarily an appropriate one, of course).

If it's really easy to "fix" with an edit (which I often do), it's definitely not something you should be downvoting or closing a question over.

---

Be optimistic. Try your best to see what the asker wants and edit the question into something appropriate, if at all possible.

---

To this end, I also propose we favour **actually explaining what's wrong with the question as a whole** as opposed to fixating on "Can you help me". For example, if someone says:

> I can't get the correct answer with my code. Can you help me?

with no description of the output or any errors, one can also get rid of "Can you help me" as described above, although the end result is still a **terrible** question:

> How do I get the correct answer with my code?

A much better comment in such cases would be:

> Do you get any errors when trying to compile or run your code? If yes, can you post the exact error message? If no, what output are you getting? Can you also post the output you're expecting?

Alternatively or additionally, simply close it using the "debugging help" close reason.

**Simply linking here DOES NOT HELP** - at best it gives some vague guidelines for what a good question should look like (which can be found in the help center as well), where concrete guidance specific to their situation would be much more beneficial to them (in my opinion). They'll probably ignore it anyway, but there's presumably a slightly greater chance that they won't.

---

If you happen to find yourself in the middle of a discussion of whether "Can someone help me?" is an 'actual' question, then I'd agree that linking here makes sense, but I'd argue that bringing this up smells of unnecessary nitpicking (unless it was done as just a note as part of an edit) - I'm not all that concerned with a user asking a question containing all the "bad" phrases like "Hi. My name is ...", "I'm new here", "I don't know what to do", "Can you help me" and "Thanks in advance" (despite obsessively editing them out of posts), as long as the rest of the post clearly describes the problem.

Don't focus on the definition of an "actual" question, which can just be confusing and lead to a question that's still not any better. Instead, lead posters towards the actual question they meant to ask and point out the details necessary for that question (or just close it as unclear or too broad if it's not salvageable).

That's not at all to say this thread in itself isn't useful - the more agreed-upon guidelines we have, the better.  It's more the unqualified linking here that I have a problem with.

Comment: More often, it just evaluates to "gimme teh codez."

Comment: I can't agree that linking here doesn't help. There are a lot of people on SO who *need* to understand the principles in this Q/A. Sure; specific guidance is great (though difficult at scale). FWIW this whole question was spawned by an actual conversation (in comments) where the OP *insisted* that asking for "general help with his project" was an acceptable question here.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I probably would've instead opted to point out that's way too broad, some specific things that can be answered to justify it being too broad and possibly mentioned why being too broad is a problem (or I would've just voted to close it). To me, "can you help me" is implied in every single question, similar to "thanks in advance" or "I don't know what to do" - removing it generally has absolutely no effect on the appropriateness of the question, so putting a significant amount of focus on it seems illogical.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Part of the problem is perhaps that you're referring to a very specific usage of the question, whereas I see this post linked **any time** the question appears in a post, which is presumably not what you intended when you originally posted this.

Comment: Asking a good question is a skill like any other, and we do the community a disservice to simply point people to this question when they don't yet have the vocabulary to process it, and all they see is a bunch of old men on the porch grumping about the damn kids. We might not be in the business of teaching people to program, but if we don't TEACH people to ask questions, we are doing a disservice to the world we are supposed to be improving.

Answer (score 27):

It **is** an actual question, but it's very unproductive and it fails to convey any useful meaning. It conveys that you have a problem and you're asking for help, but we take that for granted since you asked a question in the first place. It doesn't convey anything about what your problem *is*.

Furthermore, it's a useless question. The correct answer is “Yes” for almost all problems you will have, but that doesn't help you with your actual problem.

The same goes for asking “May I ask a question?” and similarly, for stating doubt as a question, “I think X does Y?”, which neither asserts why you think it, nor asks whether X in fact does Y.

Comment: - I think X does Y?
- Let me find my cristal ball...

Comment: I should point out that if "I think X does Y?" is part of locating a specific bug and you have isolated a small subsection of something inseparable as the potential cause, then stating it as a doubt seems fairly reasonable to me *if* it's not the main question or goal of the post. For instance, "I think line 5 is where the memory leak occurs?". There's nothing wrong with expressing doubt. It has a time and a place.

Comment: @user64742 On the other hand, Y might be a red herring, similar to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). Here's an example from just yesterday: [Does the python interpreter implicitly use the chinese remainder theorem?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69776682/4518341) A better title might be, "Why is exponentiation followed by modulus so fast when just exponentiation is so slow?"

Comment: It is forum behaviour. It is call to action and an attempt to address someone (like in a letter or email).

Answer (score 24):

The premise of SO is to get help from other people. The question "can someone help me?" is implied within every decent SO question.

If the asker is looking for ongoing help, a tutor, programmers for hire, etc. this isn't the place to look for that.

Comment: Actually, with the advent of Jobs, Stack Overflow now might be a place to look for programmers for hire. Not the main site, sure, but a branch of it.

Comment: _"The premise of SO is to get help from other people"_ -- incorrect. It is to serve as a long term repository of good questions and answers for future searchers. Failure to understand this is at the root of all of SO's problems.

Comment: @JimGarrison Incorrect answers *may* be useful, too, as long as they a) have a negative score to clearly indicate that they're incorrect answers and b) have comments explaining why the answer's incorrect. This is especially the case if the bad answer describes a wrong approach that other people are likely to try themselves.

Comment: I think the subject here is bad questions, not bad answers.

Comment: @JimGarrison at the root of any post that isn't made for the pure sake of *curiosity* there is the implied question of whether or not what I want can be fixed, accomplished, optimized, etc. Hence, posts inherently ask for help in some form or fashion. Otherwise... why even make a post? (I'm not counting Q & A posts by one person to introduce new info)

Comment: True. However, helping the OP is a secondary goal. The best questions are ones that other people will also encounter.

Comment: To elaborate further cause I re-stumbled onto this thread I would say that the goal of stack exchange is to help people solve problems. Just being a repository is not a sustainable model for a site unless people actually use that repository. So it is still a place to get help from other people even if it is people from 5 years ago who were helping someone else. Failure to understand that completely defeats the purpose of even *making* the repository this site functions as.

Answer (score 22):

Many questions receive downvotes because of the *lack of effort* put into the diagnoses of the *issue at hand*.

I could blindly post a code here and ask "why doesn't this work?", with whatever polite phrasing you like, but that won't change the fact that the issue at hand is a simple search query. This is what most questions are like in my expertise tags.

If I wrote code, tested it line by line and function by function so as to know exactly what is happening with the code, and *still* couldn't figure out how to solve the problem, I'd ask a question about it. However, questions like this are uncommon on Stack Overflow.

If you diagnose the issue, know what is happening, have an example output to your code and are still unable to fix it, I have no issue upvoting the question. It shows you have done your research and have put effort into writing a clear and solid question.

However, people will often just dive into [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and using a library (such as [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) or [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony)) without understanding how the base language really works or knowing what arrays are. If you don't know you are using a library or even understand the basic structure of programming, is this site really the best place to ask repetitive questions?

I'm asking because I cannot think of a specific issue in my expertise that is unanswered here on this site. When was the last time you read a question that shows the actual [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and shows debugging output, the data needed to resolve the issue quickly?

---

Nowadays I find most questions lazy; they are asked by people unwilling to [look for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) an answer and who most importantly have never heard of testing. They blindly copy and paste code and expect us to fix it for them.

That is where I draw the line. I try to be helpful; but if I need to put more effort into a comment than an answer, it just shows how lazy people are. And even if I did answer the question, there is a huge chance that, because they only care about themselves, they wouldn't upvote or accept an answer.

---

In conclusion: let's revisit the question, "Can someone help me?". Sure we can. However, does that result in a positive search engine query? Does it help the site in the long run, having 300m questions with the same title? Or is it maybe your psychiatrist you want help from? Yes, a lot of time has been spend on creating that title, about as long as it takes someone else to click the down vote button.

Answer (score 6):

Well I think the issue at hand here has to first be defined. I could end literally any post with a general plea of "please help". That doesn't invalidate a post or require its deletion. That's silly of course. So therefore we need to not think of "Can someone help me?" posts as a way of *phrasing* a post and more as a *type* of question.

The fallacy here is that "Can someone help me?" posts need not contain the actual phrase. The theme of these posts is that they don't try to solve their own problem. Consider this "mock" example.

> [code dump]
>
> I keep getting this compiler error.
>
> [insert compilation error]
>
> Why does it occur?

That question suffers from lack of effort. They don't attempt to interpret the compiler error.

Another kind is when someone asks "How do I do X?".

Note that all varies. I'd argue that asking "How do I re-implement this code without using ____ type control statements?. Is possibly valid. It's even more valid if it is truly **impossible** to do and can lead to interesting statements about said impossibility. After all, if it isn't possible there won't be an attempt that isn't in vain (and therefore maybe not worth sharing).

On the other hand, asking how to implement a 3D renderer from scratch... is not reasonable.

The ***ONLY*** exception to the things I have written so far ***is when the asker is also answering their post right away***. I.e. the post is just a way to share a useful piece of code. That's fair, imo. After all, why would a person sharing code write an attempt in their Q&A question? That would surely be a waste of effort. XD

Answer (score -13):

It's a language thing. Every single question on the Stack Exchange platform implicitly is asking for help. In the end, this phrase is just clutter and can be removed.

In addition to the other answers: In some cases just editing the question (removing the clutter, helping with formulating the question) and answering it may work.

Just remove the "Can you help me?" (it's just clutter) or  internally translate "Can you help me with X?" (X is the rest of the post) into "How to do X" / "How can I achieve X?" or "What is the reason for X?" (depending on X) and then answer and vote according to that.

The questioner will hopefully see the actions and learn to ask more concisely next time. One might add a comment reminding the contributor to be more specific with formulating a question and leaving out the clutter.

In some, maybe most cases, the actual question will be unclear (with or without an explicit "can you help me") and should be closed. But if the question without the "can someone help me" is still a valid question one should consider improving it and answering it.

Comment: The problem is not wording, the problem is people "just looking for help" as opposed to having a specific question

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Everyone asking a question is "just looking for help". Not having a specific question at all means that the question should be closed. Having a specific question but not formulating it well means that you can improve the question and then answer it, if you want or you downvote and move on.

Comment: You are correct, this Q/A was written to respond to people saying we *shouldn't* be closing them. Commonly the lack of a specific question seems to be accompanied by "Can someone help me?" hence the title

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Sure, but while it's common, it's not a 100% thing. In some cases it's still a valid question and then editing and answering it is recommended. Just wanted to add that with my answer.

Comment: Btw. it's also a language thing. Just look at the search for ["can someone help me"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22can+someone+help+me%22). Remarkably often the phrase is in the question title. Maybe can+someone+help should just not be allowed in titles.

Comment: Oh, I agree its not 100%. This is simply here as a guide to those questions to which it applies.

Comment: The *"How to ...?"* form is too illiterate (it is missing the auxiliary (or helping) verb). Either drop the question mark or use [standard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4yWEt0OSpg&t=1m49s) [QUASM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kS5NfSzXfrI).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Many thanks. I edited the answer.