# Why are all my questions being downvoted?

Tags: support, downvotes

I just don't get it, every time I ask a question it gets downvoted.

e.g.:

[Unable to serialize a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355057/unable-to-serialize-a-hashmap)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30277244/how-to-recover-deleted-data-using-java

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177896/how-to-encrypt-outputstream-and-decrypt-inputstream

I don't really like to be banned. What am I doing wrong? The question I asked few mins ago was very well formatted.

Comment: Two out of the three questions are closed, which has a detailed explanation of the problem(s) with the questions, along with references on how to go about addressing those problems.  Note that having a question well formatted is certainly important for a question to be a good question, but it's *far* from *sufficient*.  There are all sorts of other things that a question needs to do right.

Comment: The last two, and especially the last one, are *really* broad. Consider reading http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @Servy put that in an answer so I can accept it, that isn't a comment

Comment: Just a side note: being downvoted without getting at least some explanation in a comment is pretty unlucky. People are not forced to explain themselves, but I can assure you that plenty of people do not shy away from offering assistance to improve questions back to an up-votable state, or explain to you why your question is not salvageable (usually because its a duplicate).

Comment: It usually makes sense to add a comment saying why a question got down vote, people improve over time, at least this question got so many up-votes :)

Comment: Pay attention to which questions get upvoted and which get downvoted. You'll see a pattern and figure out what makes a good question. With more practice, you'll figure out how to ask questions which will get many upvotes and few downvotes.

Comment: it's not always question. some people here are petty, false tin gods. ive asked simple straightforward direct questions which get downvoted for no reason. maybe because it didn't suit their own narcissistic definition of a good question. there should be away to track who downvoted. I would seek out every one if their posts and hold them to their own standard.

Comment: @G: _I would seek out every one if their posts and hold them to their own standard._ You shouldn't. Going after people is strictly against the rules and will be reverted and maybe punished as well.

Comment: Small nitpick: do not abuse bold. In the text of a question you should use *inline code* to reference variables/classes/file names etc mentioned in or relevant to the code. Examples taken from your first question: `NotSerializableException` instead of **NotSerializableException** and `HashMap` instead of HashMap.  In this way it's evident what's code and what is description.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Let's talk about this on a case-by-case basis.  That's how I view questions/answers, regardless of who's asking/answering.

The question https://stackoverflow.com/q/30277244/1079354 asks a very broad question in and of itself (How do I recover deleted data?).  The reason that this is broad is easy enough to enumerate:

- how the data was destroyed
- if the data was encrypted
- if there is the possibility of any fragmentation of data
- If there is the possibility of data corruption (very possible)

Doesn't matter what language you do it in, that's a very broad statement.  There's no one definitive, absolute or authoritative approach to data recovery in *any* language or any platform, and various data recovery experts have varying results depending on the integrity of the file system.

Think "too many unknowns".

Next, the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177896/how-to-encrypt-outputstream-and-decrypt-inputstream asks a straightforward enough question (in the title); you want to encrypt output and decrypt input.

That's not such a bad thing.  But, what is it missing?

- How the data is actually encrypted
- What approach/steps/code you've taken
- The explanation is muddled at best; it's unclear how you're deploying `OutputStream` and `InputStream` in this context to achieve your goal
- The request is effectively, "Could someone explain encryption to me?"  This is a **very** broad request; few of us have the volunteer time or inclination to explain something as complex and multifarious as encryption.

Think "conceptually large".

Your final question - [Unable to serialize a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355057/lunable-to-serialize-a-hashmap) acts a reasonable enough question.  This seems like something that one would encounter, but it's missing information.  Read the comments there and add clarification as best as you can.

For that one, I personally would not downvote, but it would need to have some more context (how you're actually performing the serialization in your application with just enough code to replicate the scenario) before I would consider upvoting it.

Comment: The two "too broad" questions effectively read as "show me how to implement the whole thing" rather than a focused, specific question as well.

Comment: Note: "too broad" is the reason to close a question. It is not the reason to downvote it (that would be "question does not show any research effort" -- though the latter is correlated with the former).

Comment: But @J.F., any *reasonable* amount of research should have shown the OP just how broad those topics are.