# Is/Should this site be used by novices

Tags: discussion, etiquette

The main question is that in order to be fair to those who may have paid for classes and use programming for business and professional uses, and understand the basics as well as the depth of their selected practice. Is there a place for a novice such as myself who only knows basic HTML, PHP, CSS, MySQL?

For example I still spend a lot of time on a certain website (not sure if I can use their name) but its a W & 3 & school. I've attempted to contribute answers but I really don't or haven't found anything to contribute. So I don't feel I should ask an "novice" question which will fill the sites database with extra "dumb" questions to search for and get in the way.

I attempt to follow all the guidelines before I ask, but some questions just need a plain answer from a different perspective or explanation style that someone on here could probably answer and may be relatively valid.

So in conclusion. If the site seems overwhelming to me should I just stay out or be silent onlooker until I can start to contribute?

EDITED MUCH LATER*

After attempting the answers given I found out myself that the answer is mostly No. I have various in depth reasons for this conclusion which I don't think anyone who would disagree would care to hear anyway. I have found however that the most helpful thing is the live chat rooms, you can freely just ask simple questions, and people are very helpful much less toxic. Only issue I have is that you need certain amounts of rep and other what not to use the live chat rooms which is somehow supposed to prove your an "active" member prior to gaining access. In short I "personally" found the site's Q & A section profoundly useless, yet the simple live chat to be reasonable useful. I found that for beginners you will have a much greater success in finding answers elsewhere stack just comes up first in google searches unfortunately. It appears a lot of the sites regulations are highly subjective and perspective. So if your new somehow gain access to live chat and be polite and know what you want to ask and ask it there if no one want to bite you may want to rethink what your asking don't just spam post.

Comment: If the site is overwhelming you, a good way to figure out how it works better _is_ to lurk a bit. See what works and what does. Read up discussions on Meta, read through various help center articles. And if you have questions about the help center articles, search on Meta for answers and if you can't find anything, feel free to ask to better understand things. Basic/beginner questions aren't bad- My first question (and one of my most upvoted) was a really really novice question, but it went over well because I wrote it well. Your question just has to be well written and not missing anything.

Comment: @Deduplicator Teach them about _paragraphs_ with a decent edit.

Comment: Start by searching for the answers first, then search again.  When you find a Q&A which applies to your issue don't just take in the technical parts.  If the Q is upvoted, study it to see how it is formatted and posed to work out *why* it is considered a good question. Keep in mind though standards change and a Q from 2010 might not be as warmly accepted today.

Comment: This seems to be more about novice *programmers* not necessarily novice users to the site, and is also focused on questions instead of other posts. I'm not sure this is a duplicate

Comment: After reviewing the post that was sent as duplicate(thank you i did check it out). I feel that the fellow asking the question is probably a good/trained programmer that needed help with points and badges. To be fair ill say its 70% the same. but the conclusion is different DO/SHOULD i have even any place here? Am i at risk of wasting professional peoples time? Or if I ask very well thought out questions am i OK.

Comment: @Andymechanical Short answer, yes, you do. I have a post ready if this gets reopened.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You may want to clarify which question you are answering. ;)

Comment: @Anonymous Fair enough, Yes, you have a place here, yes, you *could* waste our time (my pending post touches on this) and yes, you are ok if you have a good question :)

Comment: VTRO.  The site is welcoming to novices who have done their homework research, and have crafted a decent question.  It isn't for novices who have done nothing and don't care about anyone or anything other than getting their next fix.

Comment: Lurking is definitely the way forward. No better way to get to grips with the site

Comment: "be polite and know what you want to ask". If people followed this on the *main* site they would likely have better received posts (most don't have a clue what they are really asking about)

Answer (score 11):

**Yes** It should absolutely be used by novices.

Now, that being said, there are a lot of mistakes novice programmers (and users) tend to make that give them a negative experience here:

1. Not searching for their question beforehand. There are *millions* of questions on this site. Most of the time, the answer is already here!
2. Asking for way too much, or otherwise not properly scoping their question. See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) for more.
3. Not including their code, a problem statement, or other important details. If you don't ask a question, or provide enough information to *answer* the question, you are wasting our time, which makes us sad. It also makes us want to downvote you.
4. Using bad grammar, formatting, etc. Paragraphs, capitalization, grammar, spelling, and code formatting **matter**. A giant wall of impossible to read text is a surefire way to have your post ignored at best, and likely closed/downvoted.
5. Asking questions to the effect of "Debug my (wall of) code for me". Ok, it's not a duplicate, but is that *really* a useful question? These questions can be generalized, and only if it is not *then* a duplicate, asked.

As some commentors have noted, a *great* strategy is to lurk around the site and notice the charecteristics of successful questions. It is *absolutely* possible to write good "basic" questions, it just takes effort on your part.

Comment: It all depends on what you're definition of "use" is. :)