# Is my question too broad?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen, editing-help, on-hold

I asked a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227218/how-can-i-make-an-app-that-saves-user-data-to-the-cloud-that-can-be-shared-with that got put on hold as too broad, and I am really confused as to why it would be marked as such.

According to the explanation of too broad, it means either:

a.) There are either too many possible answers
 I don't see how this could apply, as I thought I specified clearly enough even before my edits that I want to do this with Google services. Surely there aren't that many Google services, are there?

b.) Good answers would be too long for this format
 As near as I can imagine, a good answer would consist of a name of one of the services and maybe a brief description, unless someone thought of an approach with one of the services that I hadn't thought of, which again doesn't seem it would be particularly bulky.

As none of the people who voted it on hold left any comments, I am left scratching my head as to what just happened here. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can anyone recommend what Google services might be the closest match
>   to what I'm going for? A Google cloud service that saves data per
>   user, but allows the user to specify other users that can access the
>   data?

This is basically asking for a recommendation, which is not the close reason given, but it easily *could* have been.

That being said, the titular question (and to a lesser extent, the body) read as "How do I implement this feature". These kinds of questions are almost *always* too broad, since features require multiple files, many, many lines of code, etc.

Also See:
[Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I don't see how I'm asking for implementation. I've been searching for any Google service that will do what I'm asking, and coming up dry. If I have to roll my own, I can do that,    I'm just trying to see if the capabilities I want already exist in something Google provides.

Comment: I've revised the question to try to sound less like "implement this for me".

Comment: The fact that you are unable to understand why it is too broad does not mean that it isnt actually too broad.  You've now got a lot of downvotes and close votes which means that you will be on the edge of the automatic question ban.  So it would be a good idea to put more effort into understanding the rules before you ask your next question. Your edit changed the question to be "recommend this for me" which is just a different reason to close it.  Its still a bad question.

Comment: @JK I assume that was meant for the OP? Do note that unless you have asked *other* poorly recieved questions, you probably aren't on the edge of the ban from that one post.

Comment: @Trevortni It does still read as a recommendation question, but *so specific* that its almost answerable. One other thing to consider would be asking this at Software Reccomendations, where such questions are explicitly allowed.

Comment: Ummm. Software Recommendations?

Comment: @Trevortni http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay, thank you for that. I must admit to still being perplexed about this whole downvote and on-hold issue though. Especially being downvoted here, when I'm doing exactly what the help for the site explicitly told me to do if I'm unsure: http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions.

Comment: @Trevortni You invoked the meta effect on yourself, showing your off-topic question to lots of high-interest users (who are likely to downvote such questions). Also note that questions on meta often indicate disagreement instead of a lack of quality. If you have questions about the site, many answers are already here, but if you can't find one, feel free to ask.

Comment: Sigh. I would ask a question about whether having official recommendations be noob-bait is a good idea, but I think I'd better quit while I'm ahead (or merely a little bit behind).

Comment: One last thing though - are we sure Software Recommendations isn't going to downvote me for asking a programming question?

Comment: @Trevortni Your question isn't a programming one, and library recommendations are explicitly on-topic. In its current form, I would think its narrow enough to fit there.

Comment: Well, thank you. At least I got my Meta question answered.

Comment: Okay, I've submitted the question in Software Recommendations. Thanks again!

Comment: ..and then, THIS happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493111/what-is-a-simple-and-reliable-c-library-for-working-with-excel-files