# Should I insert some code when asking for idea?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, code

I'm having a problem with the following thing:

Today I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474164/perl-get-array-of-all-possible-cases-of-a-string?lq=1) about getting all cases of a word in **Perl**, and, to my mind, wrote the question exactly the same way as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747123/combination-of-all-possible-cases-of-a-string?lq=1). However, if that other question was marked as good, and clear, and relevant, mine was criticized for having no code and asking to do all the dirty job.

I don't really care about reputation as long as it doesn't fully restrict my priveleges which it's nice to have (50 reputation isn't much, so I don't have to struggle with it), but this is as ridiculous as if it was a question about how to tame hungry lions with an old-fashioned shoe, or how to build a tree in tetris, or could anyone write all the thing for me (I can't even understand, which one is it).

By the way, I have always had problems with essays, being punished for 'illogical' conclusions.

Here is the *original* post:

> I need to get an array of all possible cases of a string. Like it's
>   written here:
>
> [Combination of all possible cases of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747123/combination-of-all-possible-cases-of-a-string)
>
> How do I do that in **Perl** efficiently?
>
> **Note**
>
> I tagged `glob` because it's the function to which I want to feed the
>   result, so people as me will later find the question. However, The
>   question is not only about this particular case of usage.

Comment: Since you are asking if you should have had code, I added the original (no-code) revision to the post. Feel free to revert/modify if you wish

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, thanks for help, this is my first post on Meta.

Comment: For starters, explain your problem in _your_ post.  People aren't going to want to click to another post to understand your problem.  What if that question were deleted (or the link broke)?  Would anyone be able to understand what you wanted?  The way it is written right now I certainly wouldn't be able to.

Comment: For every bad, off topic question, you can find an example of the same that has been upvoted and hasn't been closed.  That sort of thing happens when humans are involved and the total number of questions is almost 10 million.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the other question is from 2011. That's not the wild days of 2008, but its still far enough back that the standards have evolved since then. Basically, don't use an old post being upvoted as evidence that similar questions are good today.

To answer the titular question, **yes** you should absolutely show code that has expected usage, any attempts you have made, etc. This shows research and effort at the very least.

Your original revision is very broad and "give me teh codez" feeling. I'm not surprised it was downvoted. Also see: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 4):

That older question you linked is from 2011. Standards have changed, since then.

If that exact same question were to be posted today, it would receive the same votes as yours had.

You should always provide an explanation of what you tried, what isn't working, and why it's not working. Any errors you're getting, or specific problems you're running into can help.

Stack Overflow is not a site where you can post code requests.

Comment: Thanks! But If I'm coding a program, and need to implement a feature, but I've got no Idea how to make it any kind of elegant, can't I ask for that? Or I should always provide a specific question with a ten lines of code and ask something like "how to apply simplex method in c++ physical engine AF-4324 Beta?"

Comment: Can't make both answers accepted, sorry.