# There should be a section for finding bugs in code?

Tags: discussion, scope

Someone may have already asked this but I think there should be a section on this site for finding bugs in code because its not exactly asking a question and when I've tried asking questions about bugs in my code in the past I just get down voted by everyone, its a little discouraging. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 18):

Thought: Debug your own code. We aren't a debugging service (though many people *think* we are one). If you can't formulate a proper question about it, it **definitely** doesn't belong here.

That said, *great* questions can come out of debugging, but it requires finding and asking about the actual root problem (not just "it doesn't work"). More at: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: BradleyDotNET why is everyone so negative on this site. What happens when you've tried debugging your own code for the last 5 days and have exausted all the questions that you've come up with yourself, went through all your old textbooks and still have no idea, what than

Comment: @JeremySills Then you should have enough information to form a proper question. If you are still at "It doesn't work" then I don't have a good suggestion, other than not an SE site. We really aren't here to do it for you.

Comment: @JeremySills: Why are you on this site? Because you can find good Q&A, and also ask questions and get answers to them, which adds to the former. What do you think would happen if we didn't curate those? If you mistake that for being negative, so be it.

Comment: @jeremysills take a chill pill dude, no one insulted you.  In general, bradley is right. if you've tried to debug your own code you should have a "I tried to foo the bar, but the grotnik seems misconfigured, even though I pass the proper options in my code" which is already way better than "my code doesn't work". You came here asking for feedback, they answered you. No reason to push back that hard.

Comment: @Patrice thats what I'm saying though when you have no questions left to ask what can you say

Comment: @jeremysills start fresh? Try to provide a minimal example exposing what you have as an issue. often when trying to create a minimal example I realize where my error lies (since the codebase is that much smaller). And I'm sorry but if you've tried to fix your issue for 5 days, it's impossible you don't have ANY clue besides "it doesn't work".

Comment: @jeremysills as a sidenote, having a section of stack dedicated to such questions breaks the intent of stack. Stack is supposed to be a good, long lasting repository of Q&As, who will be useful to future visitors. Highly unlikely anyone will ever try to search for a "this doesn't work. What do I do now?" kind of post.

Comment: If user has been debugging for five days, a  user with all the source, compiler, debugger, logger, environment etc and could not trace the problem, it is extremely unlikely that any SO question could help anyone.  The code/data is likely tl;dr, as would be all the debugging details built up over the five days.  'what than' - you're stuffed, SO cannot help you.

Answer (score -3):

Hmm..  this idea has some merit. If all the 'could not be bothered to do any debugging' and 'I did some debugging, but could not be bothered to list my results' questions could be given a section of their very own, it would be great!  I'm all for it! Do it now!  Please!