# Why do people downvote my questions instead of asking to improve them?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, scope, downvote-reason

I wrote *[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588297/how-to-create-an-interactive-fictional-graph-map-in-android)* some minutes ago where I was looking for help and got five downvotes after less than 10 minutes. It's also inspired on [an old and no more effective question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584726/how-to-implement-an-interactive-graph-map-in-android) which instead got 1.

I understand that questions have also to be helpful for other people and not just for me, but seriously I can't understand this.

I got told this "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

The problem is that I don't know how to get started since this problem feels really difficult for me as there are really few resources to resolve it. It's not something like C++ vs Java which could bring thousands of opinion-based answers; it's about a thing that for me it's just difficult to do.

Above all among so many downvotes no one even tried to suggest me a solution, so if my question can generate so many "attract opinionated answers" why didn't get 1?

And why can the other question I linked be considered legitimate while mine is not?

He also asked for help like this

> I'm about to start a new project and am currently stuck at the research stage. I'm trying to find clues as to how to implement an interactive map of sorts.

But it wasn't pissed off so much by downvotes.

This is the opposite of helping, and while I'm making questions like this and getting downvoted, the first person who creates a question "Hey how to create an array in Java" which could be found in every book or guide gets 1000+ upvotes, and this feels mostly a load of dingo's kidneys.

Can you explain me here without downvoting what was really wrong? If there is a way I can ask again my problem in a better way tell me and vote my question I linked to delete it, so I start a new one in a way where I respect better rules. I didn't intend to offend anybody; it was just a question!

Comment: There's one thing here you didn't think about... Stack is NOT meant for "helping". It's meant to be a repository of great programming content. And YES you were really wrong. There is an off-topic reason explicitely stating what you did wrong..... what else can we say?

Comment: Oh and looking at a 2-3 year old question as a reference that your question is good can't really be done. This website is in constant evolution, so the rules change

Comment: People ask here everyday thousands of questions for getting help and this is not meant for helping? I think it's mean for helping at the same time being a big repository of great programming content. Why are you talking so serious, I just wrote a question and it looks like everybody is hating me for it. I don't get always when a question is offtopic and you would help better saying it than blaming me for it.

Comment: And above all why downvote this? We are in meta stack overflow, what's the need in downvoting questions here? I'm questioning to understand and you still downvote. This is not helpful at all.

Comment: voting is different on META, you don't lose points for it.

Comment: What I can suggest you do is take the [tour], read [ask], and take those words to heart. The downvotes here probably are for "lack of research" since these kinds of questions are covered in those linked pages.

Comment: well look, I explain to you you misunderstand the site and you fight back. Do you get why people are not keen on jumping into these conversations, because new users tend to not listen? Stack is for PRECISE problems. You come with "hey I'm trying to set this up, and calling this method, I get this weird behavior instead of this behavior". You don't come with "how do I do X"

Comment: I understanding that voting here doesn't affect points but still could be avoided. Downvoting should be more for useless posts instead of "I don't like this"

Comment: Please don't go emotional on us over here. StackOverFlow provides always provide a reason for 'Closing' a question or such similar activity. The downvotes? Well, someone amongst the downvoters will probably tell you the reason in comments if you are unable to figure it out yourself. Besides, go through the provided links and may be you will ask better questions.

Comment: Again the question I did was about a difficult task I have to do and it's not even simple to get started. Since it's not a featured thing, it wouldn't have generated for sure dozens of different answers, and above all I'd have appreciated even just once. I read the tour but still for me it isn't clear and the way you write is offensive since it sounds more like a blame than an actual information. I'm not fighthing back, I'm just asking.

Comment: Dude, I tell you "stack is not meant to help, it's a repository of knowledge" and you say "no".... how is this not fighting back?. Anyway, whether there's ONE tool that solves your issue or half a dozen is irrelevant. Asking for stuff like that will start argumentation in answers about "my answer is better because my tool can do X that yours can't", and make answers awful to maintain (if the tool goes out of circulation, the answer is just crap). Whether it's hard or simple is irrelevant. We have clear info on what's on topic and not...

Comment: Downvotes are for lack of research, so a question like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java which could be resolved in a 1min Google research gets 745 upvotes, while mine that is a problem is struggling me for DAYS is a bad question. Explain me this please.

Comment: AGAIN, you pull old questions. Do you realize that? I just told you "the site evolves and changes, so do the rules"

Comment: Still it was a lackily research question that could have been resolved just in a book or in a guide but was upvoted to the 745 degree while mine was just an asking for recommendation and was downvoted. I got the thing about going offtopics and generating tons of answers, but I think my problem was too difficult to get tons of answers. Some could ofc have helped me, just I don't think it'd have had hundreds of comments on how to do it in a different way since it's a hard task, again, it's not like "it's better java or c++", it was a precise things and I was just asking for a solution

Comment: A solution WE needed to do 100% of?... this is NOT how stack works. Yes the question you linked lacked research. But back in that time (6 years ago is not relevant) rules were different and that question was handled with the rules relevant AT THE TIME.

Comment: Again, I wasn't asking for you to resolve my problem, just to recommend a way to get started. The question wasn't so easy to reply that everybody could have done it, it was asking precise things.

Comment: Maybe I lacked research in the post but I did a lot in this days and found nothing. I come here for help and I get pissed off by everybody.

Comment: no one is pissed off at you, we're explaining WHY your question should not have been asked and why it's off topic... Which is what you requested. Again, do you understand why frequent users don't necessarily explain downvotes? the conversation in the comments summarizes what happens 95% of the time... "oh ok yeah I get the rules, but MY CASE is special"

Comment: 8 downvotes if I ask in a meta zone for clarifyng and it's not pissing off? Maybe I can get them in the normal Stackoverflow, but this metazone is meant for things like this so why downvote even here. This feels like the hate for what I ask.

Comment: Don't take what's being said personally.  Maybe you should cool off for a bit?

Comment: Nope because you could hold back the downvote button at least in this meta question but you didn't even here. This is why I get this personally, this is not actually helping or explaining, this is pissing off and blaming me because I didn't get the rules as well as you did.

Comment: so I count 4 users (me, Makoto, Sorrel, and Mike) who tried to help you and answer your question. As opposed to 8 downvotes. Why don't you focus on the 4 guys trying to help you instead of the meaningless score of your question here?

Comment: *"Why people downvote my questions instead of asking to improve them"* Those are two very separate actions. Downvotes are meant to judge quality and usefulness, they have nothing to do with improving questions. It's easy to vote on quality/usefulness, but much harder to come up with ways to make the content useful or of higher quality, Especially in your specific case where your question can't be salvaged because it is entirely off topic.

Comment: The question you linked to as a *good* example is now closed and at -2

Comment: I feel bad for him. I don't remember if he had 1 or 6 upvotes when I linked his question, but if its question was old and legit at that year rules, he didn't deserve these recent downvotes.

Comment: Well at least now I got why my question got downvoted while his one not (at its time).

Comment: His question was used by you to justify your question. It's less likely that will happen in future at least with that question so the downvotes are rather useful (again not to him but to others).

Comment: That is called the "meta effect". By linking something into meta, you make it more visible to people who care about the quality of the site. So good questions linked into meta get more upvotes, bad questions get down and close votes

Comment: Well this was finally a good explanation of downvotes context. I liked also Kevin B recommendation (which sorry Patrice, but nobody of you told me) to ask something in a chatroom if doesn't fit rules.

Comment: Just a point of detail. You were asking from your post how to improve your question. Over time, you realized Stack was not the proper way and you formulated "what can I do". Two different questions, two different answers

Comment: @user1714647 Please note that questions in the chat room also have to be on topic for that chat room. Each chat room has it's own set of rules. If you don't follow them, you'll likely be ejected from the room.

Comment: At least I don't get downvoted with the accuse of ruining this site quality with my "poor" questions. I don't think I can misfollow even chatroom rules btw.

Comment: Tip for being on meta in general... don't go in hyperbole, it will NEVER help you. No one accused you of ruining the site, don't make it sound like anyone did...

Comment: Maybe because downvoting questions is free!

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Each time I post a question here, there is someone that is downvoting without reason. So how can I contact with the administrator of stackoverflow in order to know which person is and block it? thx.

Answer (score 27):

Don't take this personally:  this question is not suitable for Stack Overflow.

What your question is asking, ostensibly, is ***very*** broad:  you're building a game on Android, and you want help on building a piece of it.  That's a huge ask, and since you don't have anything to go off of, it's tough for us to even *begin* to help you.

We can't be used as a sounding board for those who are just getting started.

Once you have a ***specific*** question to ask, then feel encouraged to ask it.

Comment: I'm not a Stackoverflow Expert which knows all types of questions defined legit and how not. You guys said the rules change so I can't even get inspired by old posts.
I don't know how much specific has a question to be in order to be accpetable, but if it is I get always 0 upvotes, while if it isn't, half of this community comes in my post to downvote and this is what feels wrong for me.

Comment: I personally don't expect you to be an expert, since you've had such little exposure to the site.  However, this is the way you learn about what is and isn't a valuable question on the site:  by asking us about it here on Meta.  I will commend you for at least doing that, since there are so many others that don't bother to.  A simple rule of thumb to keep in mind would be to ensure that your question is specific, clear, and relates to a particular problem as opposed to it being something that's incredibly broad.  Stick to that, and you'll *generally* be alright.

Comment: If the meta is meant for asking questions like this, while is even this question getting downvotes?

Comment: [Voting is different on Meta.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)  It likely means that people are disagreeing with the premise that your question is going after.

Comment: honestly? a) it sounds like a rant. b) you ask for reasons on a question where the closure reason WAS stated (you even include it in your post) c) this is discussed frequently on meta, a little research could've helped you there. d) some people might not appreciate the tone of some of your comments? e) tim lost his keys.... again

Comment: People started downvoting before there were actually comments. Downvoting should be related for something useless or spamming, not for something that people don't like

Comment: ... on the main site, yes. as I've stated (and makoto as well), voting on meta is different... Anyway the comment is one of 5 possible reasons I gave... yet, again, you focus on ONE thing and fight back on that....

Comment: @user1714647:  Voting is arbitrary and by design.  For all you know, [they may have lost their keys.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/175248)  Besides, your definition of "useless" may not jive with others' definition of "useless"; you may think your question isn't useless, but others would very strongly disagree with that premise.

Comment: Anyway if asking for recommendations can get very broad, it's not always like that. The more a question is generic and just asks for opinions, it is broad, but my question, opinion-based or not was about a really specific thing that in any case would have NEVER attracted dozens of users to reply, so I think that as programmers you are, and as I am, the common sense could have come before the rules. I didn't meant to offend anybody, just the problem looked to me specific enough to ask here it, I read really well the rules about opinionbased posts in the past (and not far past)

Comment: Makoto so you're telling me people are hurted (if they strongly disagree) if I ask a question that they could simply ignore

Comment: @user1714647:  What I'd say is that the quality of the site goes down if poor questions are allowed to stick around.  Again, I'm legitimately not trying to offend you, but the question you asked was poor.  To that, we use downvotes as a way to control the quality of what survives and gets seen here.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an “actual” question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/839601)

Comment: @Makoto, "Don't take it personally" may be true, but it doesn't make any of the literal thousands of similarly drive-by afflicted people any happier. What we need is people to explain this from the get-go, instead of wrecking somebody's potentially non-zero rep and walking off.