# What should I do with this user's debugging questions?

Tags: discussion

In the tag I'm active on I've seen an user post 10 questions the last 4 days and 8 of these questions are all the same format *"I have this problem, here's my code: *code dump**. Basically using Stackoverflow as a debugging service.  I don't know if I should go in and downvote all those questions, risking being flagged as a serial downvoter (I've downvoted some though).

I wanted to write a comment to the user but don't know how to explain why these questions aren't appreciated when most of them have upvotes and upvoted answers. That also makes me a bit skeptical; maybe I am wrong? I know all questions could be closed since it must contain *"the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"*, but I've seen many taking lightly at that point.

**What should I do?** (i.e. ignore it, downvote, send comment, realise I'm wrong, etc).

I don't know if I should link to this user's question, so I'll include the questions here for anonymity. After each question it should follow a code dump on average 100 lines, which I've excluded.

**Question 1**

> I'm working on a space shooter game and In that game, when an alien
>   sprite collides with a player sprite, I want the game to end. When
>   wrote the code for the collision, It didn't end the game. Can someone
>   help me?'

**Question 2**

> I'm working on a space shooter and I've made the sprites and added
>   some basic collision detection, but when I added in collision
>   detection for whether or not an alien sprite collides with the player
>   sprite, it gave me this error message:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 93, in
>   
>       game.new()   File "main.py", line 33, in new
>       self.run()   File "main.py", line 45, in run
>       self.collision()   File "main.py", line 58, in collision
>       hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.alien, False)   File
>   "C:\Users\sidna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py",
>   line 1525, in spritecollide
>       return [s for s in group if spritecollide(s.rect)] TypeError: 'Alien' object is not iterable

**Question 3**

> I'm working on a game, and In this game I need a yellow rectangle to
>   show up on the game window, but when I ran the code the yellow
>   rectangle didn't show up. I'm drawing the rectangle in the Player()
>   class. Can anyone help me?

**Question 4**

> I'm working on a game and In this game the player wins if its
>   character (a ball) has a w of 34. I made a win screen, but when I
>   tested it out, it was giving me an error message:
>
> Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "main.py", line 260, in 
>       main()   File "main.py", line 165, in main
>       gameLoop()   File "main.py", line 192, in gameLoop
>       player.end()   File "main.py", line 133, in end
>       win() TypeError: 'Text' object is not callable

**Question 5**

> I'm making The Snake Game, and in this game, when the snake hits a
>   piece of food, the length of the snake increase. The issue that I'm
>   having is that when I implemented some code that will help me make the
>   snake's length longer and tested it out, the snake was moving behind
>   the scenes but wasn't showing up. I know I have to update the display,
>   but I don't know where.

**Question 6**

> I'm working in a game, and in this game an object falls from the top
>   of the game screen and the player at the bottom of the screen has to
>   hit the object falling. When the player hits the falling object, the
>   player's width and height needs to increase. When I tested the code,
>   the collision worked when the player hit the falling object from the
>   side, but the collision didn't work when the player hit the falling
>   object in the middle. Can someone help me?

**Question 7**

> I'm working on a game, and In this game I have an object that falls
>   from the top of the game screen. When the object's y >= 200, I want
>   the object to redraw with a random x position. I tried to code it, but
>   it doesn't work. I suspect there's some issue with where I'm redrawing
>   the object. Can someone point out my mistake? The issue is in the
>   draw()

**Question 8**

> I'm working on a game, and in that game whenever the player's x is >=
>   the screen's width, I want the player's x velocity to = 0. But when I
>   tried, it didn't work. The collision code looks fine to me, I think
>   there is some issue with when I call player.collision(). PS. The
>   object's velocity is equal to 0 when the objects x is <= 0, but not
>   when the x is >= displayW the velocity doesn't equal to 0. The problem
>   is under #collision to walls

Comment: You only have to worry about serial voting if you are voting on the same person.  If separate people are posting the garbage then down votes, close votes/flagging is what you should be doing.  If it is just one low rep user posting then they should be quality banned shortly.

Comment: @NathanOliver It is the same user, but the problem is that he/she is getting upvotes on the questions. I believe they're not appropriate for SO but cannot downvote since I'll risk serial downvoting. And the fact that the questions are getting upvotes make me question what I thought was appropriate. Maybe I've been downvoting valid questions.

Comment: @Ted You can always leave a comment why you downvoted, a flag respectively if you think there's an applying one. To not be caught as serial voter by the automatic scripts, take your time to judge each post thoroughly and explain as mentioned, do not dig down at the user primarily.

Comment: Are you talking about [Siddharth Nand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7332411/siddharth-nand?tab=profile)? Because they are __suspended for voting irregularities__

Comment: As long as you vote organically, as you see the questions, you should be fine. I've encountered the same types of users, and just voting as the questions come has worked for me. I can't say this will definitely work though, as I don't know the details of the serial checker.

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes, that was the user. Wasn't sure if it considered wrong to hang someone out in a meta post.

Comment: In the future though, how can I inform someone if I suspect for example voting irregularities?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman There's no rule against it AFAIK, but it's a nice thing - not to same someone as I did :( You can flag one of his questions for a moderator and explain what's wrong with that user (Although this one is already suspended)

Comment: Use a custom moderator flag on one of the posts

Comment: see also [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an "actual" question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/839601)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you see a relatively new user dumping a bunch of poor-quality questions on the site, yet getting most or all of them upvoted, that might call for a custom moderator flag to let us look into this. This behavior could be an indication of someone using sock puppets to upvote their questions in order to permanently evade a question ban.

We can look into things and see if the votes look suspicious, or if we see any indication of previously question-banned accounts around this user. If so, we can act on that by correcting the voting and helping to prevent future bad questions from being asked.

For example, I think you'll find many of the upvotes on the above questions have disappeared and that they may not be able to ask new questions for a while.

Comment: Okay, next time I'll flag it! Just one question; even if I was relatively sure this was the case, I couldn't be absolutely sure since some of the questions weren't upvoted. Should I still flag and can I get repercussions if I'm wrong?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman - Generally, I only decline flags about suspicious votes if it's pretty obvious from a non-moderator perspective that there's nothing wrong (someone flagging Jon Skeet for sock puppets, or flagging us to look into a single up or downvote). If you see something suspicious, and explain what we should look into, I'm almost always going to treat that as being helpful even if there isn't something wrong.

Comment: I can't believe you sheeple are still denying the existence of the Skeet voting ring! When will you open your eyes to the truth?!7!

Comment: @JoshCaswell to see the truth you need a special hat. Brad doesn't have it. It's not made of tinfoil!

Comment: "Voting ring" is such a meagre description. I have a voting hypercube.