# What is the correct close reason for non-questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

My question is related to this post: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

If someone posts a "requirements dump" that doesn't contain an actual question at all (or that includes a non-question like "can someone help me?"), what is the proper close reason? Should it be closed as "too broad" or as "unclear what you're asking" - or does it matter?

Comment: Does it matter? It's both, flip a coin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there are actually three approaches. People tend to add three different close reasons:

1. Unclear what you're asking
2. Too broad
3. Off-topic - questions why isn't this code working...

I flag such questions as *Unclear what you're asking* because it automatically links **[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** when close is successful.

On the other hand I find the article **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** even more helpful.

In my opinion, too broad doesn't help the OP to learn what exactly was wrong with the question, so answering your question, don't close as too  broad as you can haunt two things at one - closing and a more meaningful message with one click using *unclear* or *why isn't...*.

Answer (score 4):

I think "unclear what you're asking" fits better.

Too broad implies a question (a question has to exist for a question to be too broad), but it really doesn't matter.

Pick what speaks to you, either will probably be fine, but I'd pick unclear.