# Why was this spam flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, spam, disputed-flags

I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44685257/1495050) as spam and the flag was disputed. I then tried a custom moderator flag and that was (almost immediately?) disputed as well.

Does this question not count as spam? It's a link to a slow, bloated website that doesn't have text changing color as far as I can tell. It's even asking people to click the link.

[image: Image of post]

Comment: It does have color changing text (see the "Our Services" near the top). They're asking how to replicate that effect. That isn't spam.

Comment: I missed that... the site loaded so slowly I gave up and started scrolling looking for color changing text before it had loaded.

Comment: It sure is an exceptionally poor question, there are several elements in that page that change text and color. The "FAQ" header for example when you scroll way down or when you hover over some of the blocks of information. Need a *You need to do more than point your finger and say "gimme that"* close reason for stuff like this...

Comment: @Gimby There's been some discussion about what the correct close reason for "gimme teh codez" question is I believe - personally, I'd love to see a "standard" close reason for "gimme teh codez" (rather than just closing them all as "too broad" or something like that).

Comment: You'll see questions like that fairly regularly in CSS/JavaScript tags. They're usually Too Broad or Unclear. But usually spam in question posts is either more blatant ("This flooring company is SUPER AWESOME!") or the spam URL is just sitting there with no reference to it all all ("Seemingly legit question...link to flooring company apropos of nothing").

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's not spam.  It's simply linking to an external site to demonstrate something it wants to do.  That doesn't make for a good question (a question should contain enough information *in the question itself* for it to be answered, although linking to an example like that *in addition* is perfectly fine), but that doesn't make it spam.  If you had flagged for closure for that reason, the flag would likely have been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't spam, just "gimme teh codez." Personally, I'd downvote, vote to close (or flag since you don't have 3K rep yet) as "too broad", and comment pointing them to some kind of documentation on how to write good questions (e.g. the "how to ask" page or [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)).

Incidentally, the downvote tooltip for questions says "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." All three of those apply here.