# Should "Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?" be a FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, specific-question, meta, canonical

It seems like [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) is now the *de facto* standard reference post on the topic. This hasn't actually been proposed as a FAQ, but can it be promoted to one anyway?

Comment: A faq definitely shouldn't be dupe-flagged, and probably should not have more than one answer. So it's not in very good shape. You might be able to ask a similarly-framed question, taking care to distinguish it and giving a good, thorough self-answer, then adding [tag:faq-proposed] and flagging for CW. (In particular, I've personally had [considerable success](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) getting a re-asked self-answered question into the faq.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy It seems like the dupe is almost never referred to, though.

Comment: @EJoshuaS it is possible that most of dupes are deleted (by Roomba or 10K votes). Think of a typical dupe, "Y my ques is downrated when it haz such a clear image of my codes", how well would it be received at MSO. Maybe diamond moderators can tell if this is the case

Comment: @gnat I was thinking more along the lines of the target for the linked post. The post I'm asking to be a FAQ was, in fact, marked as a duplicate of another post. The other question has a significantly higher score on the question itself (+326/-2 vs +82/-30), but the accepted answer for the one I want to be a FAQ has a score of +237/-0 vs +35/-4. Also, the dupe target is a feature request and the one I link to is an actual discussion question (a request for reasons that you shouldn't do that), so it's already worded (and answered) in a way that's suitable for a FAQ on the topic.

Comment: @NathanTuggy It seems like the question is already a lot more "canonical"/frequently referred to than whatever I'd be likely to write (plus it seems like that would be creating an obvious duplicate of an already-acceptable post). Some FAQs *do* have multiple answers, such as [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) (which is the current canonical post for non-questions and zero-effort requirements dumps). Full disclosure: one of the answers is mine (arguing that "can someone help me?" evaluates to "gimme teh codez").

Comment: @EJoshuaS: Honestly, that seems to be a really good example of why faqs need to have exactly one answer. Only one of the answers has a score of more than 20, which means that we have one canonical answer and a bunch of ambiguously canonical supporting info tacked on. (I upvoted several of them, but really, their good points should be folded into the main answer. That's what CW is *for*.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy You do bring up a good point. Still, it does seem like it's an intrinsic issue any time you elevate an older Meta post to FAQ status - I'm not sure that it should necessarily be excluded from FAQ status simply based on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That post was made into a [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow).