# We are no longer accepting [donations]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Burninate request for [donations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/donations):

**1.  Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

> In a way, it does describe the contents, which is when you want to create a donation-sort of function. And it is unambiguous I guess, because when you say donations, it is just to give something without expecting for anything in return

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

> I guess not, because you can also explain the problem without the tag, and most of the question just boils down to how to set-up or create an online payment function, whether it is for donations or for payments

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

> As I said, most of the question just boils down to how to set-up or create an online payment function, whether it is for donations or for payments, so not really.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

> Yes, it just means one thing: to provide a function on how users can donate to the programmer, team, etc.

As they say: **"No one can be an expert in [donations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/donations)"**

Comment: [Related gif](https://deadrabbit.barstoolsports.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/01/joker.gif)

Comment: In my opinion, I don't think tagging a question with [tag:donations] describes the content. Considering that Stack Overflow is a platform for programming-related questions, then "donations" doesn't really say anything related to the actual, programming-related content of the question.

Comment: Anyone have [donations] for Trogdor the Burninator?

Comment: Ok, I won't donate

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this should be burninated. It's describing the functionality being implemented, not the actual technology being used. Site rules dictate that you should [ask a programming question, not a question about how to implement a feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Put another way, this site is for experts in PHP, C++, C#, etc. Donation experts are at other sites, like Personal Finance SE.