# Are there special considerations when burninating non-programming concepts?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

***Introduction***

Lately, I've seen a lot of [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request)s for tags that are about concepts unrelated to programming, such as [booking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361729/7296893), [donations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361578/7296893), [shop](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361501/7296893) and more. These tags are not programming related by themselves, but more general concepts that either frequently need to be integrated in a program, or require specific kinds of programs.

There are more of these kinds of tags to be found, I'm sure (recently came across [invoices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invoices), and related to that I also found [billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/billing) and [accounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accounting), but there are probably far more that haven't been posted yet as a burninate request).

***Subjects for discussion:***

**Should we burninate all these tags using the normal system, posting one request at a time whenever we encounter one?**

<sup>That's what we're doing now, I think.</sup>

**Are there any special considerations when posting or evaluating a request to burninate such a tag?**

<sub>(I've noted that often, the word meta-tag is used in conjunction with these tags. As far as I know, meta-tags describe characteristics of the question rather than the problem (such as difficult, homework, etc.) and these tags are something a bit different)</sub>

Comment: The only consideration I can think of for not burninating with the normal system (1 request at a time) would be if there are too many of these types of tags to handle individually. Even then, unless the tags being burninated are closely related enough, it might end up muddying the request a bit. In light of that, I see no problem in continuing as we have been.