# Are questions necessarily "bad" if they don't contain an actual question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I read a lot of "questions" that don't actually contain any question.  They typically go more or less like:

> I want to do xyz. Thanks!

and if we're lucky:

> I tried `blob of code` but it didn't work.

However clear & well stated these posts are, I find it problematic to provide an answer when there's no sentence that ends in a question mark, i.e., **a question**.  I realize that it's possible to  describe a desired result, offer examples and in some cases get useful guidance from other users but it still irks me.

At the risk of appearing deliberately obstinate, I initially found myself commenting over and over again things like "*ok, what is your question?*" or "*can you please ask an actual question here?*" More recently, I just vote to close as "unclear what you're asking" since nothing was ever actually asked, but it happens so often that I've started wondering if I should rethink my stance on this.

Am I being too rigid in my thinking? Can a "question" be constructive and on-topic if it doesn't contain any actual question?

Comment: Not rigid but I wouldn't get stuck on it. Either edit to make it a question, leave a comment (something like: "Do you mean ...."  **NOT** "ok, what is your question?" as that is a bit too much passive aggressive to me) if you're unsure of intent or close as unclear if you can't make head or tails of it.

Comment: If I see a question that's literally just a title and a code or error dump, I'll upvote any comment asking what the question is. If it's a post with an actual problem description and a goal mentioned that just doesn't have a question mark at the end, I'd say it's fine.

Comment: Question quality is subjective, but if you'd make a list then "Doesn't ask a question" is surely at the top.  SO users complete it by themselves.   If they have an idea what it is about then they add "How do I do this?", if they don't then they add "Can you send me teh codez?".  Sometimes I do.  Comments not necessary btw, it is intentional.

Comment: On MSE: [Should we force users to have an actual question in their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175291)

Comment: My approach to these questions is drive-by VTC + DV; I figure if the asker actually cares enough they will fix their question, or someone else with more time than me will make a comment prompting them to fix their question. Call me lazy, but it really isn't the job of the people who donate their free time, for free, to curate this site; to pry the blood of a good question out of the stone of a bad asker. If you can't be a\*\*ed to ask a decent question, why should I be a\*\*ed to help you?

Comment: @billynoah And I'm providing my response, which is "no they're not", hence the VTC.

Comment: ok - with that in mind would you still VTC on an example like what Maroun offered?  Or do you disagree with the statement "*Question marks are not the main thing that determines the question's quality*"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Question marks are not the main thing that determines the question's quality.

Most of the users are intelligent enough to get the question, or the problem, from the post even with the absence of the question mark.

Consider the example below:

> [TITLE]
>
> Guarantee visibility of changes to variables across threads
>
> [BODY]
>
> I have the following class:
>
> ```
> public class MyObject {
>     public volatile int data = 0;
> }
> ```
>
> [GOOD EXPLANATION OF THE PROBLEM]
>
> I can't make changes visible across threads.

The problem is well defined, the code demonstrates the problem, and we know that the question is "How do I make the changes visible across all threads?". In this case, I find the question useful, although it doesn't really contain a question with a question mark.

Comment: This is a great example of where I begin doubting my attachment to the presence of an actual question.  I agree it's *very likely* that the question is what you assume — but it might not be.  And that grain of uncertainty sets off alarms in my programmer's brain.

Comment: @billynoah I totally agree. I'm not saying the programmer's intention is always clear. In the example above it's clear, and it will be very surprising if the programmer's question is "how do I terminate the thread". In other cases, if you're not sure what the question could be, you can ask for clarification and VTC if needed.

Answer (score 11):

The lack of a question mark is a smell. Usually it's bad meat, but sometimes it's good cheese. [Maroun's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378619/3942918) gives an abbreviated example of probably good enough cheese.

Unfortunately that smell has a cost. There's more doubt in the assumptions you have to make to address the author's problem. Sometimes it's only a little bit more, but it's still more.

*"What?, Why?, How?"* each can attract different sorts of answers as they give an indication of what level of information a person is after and what they can do with it. Without any of them it's less immediately obvious.

Fortunately here it's easy to have good cheese without the smell by slightly rephrasing the question into, well, a question. If you find this hard to do the cheese might not actually be so good.

---

It's worth noting that the existence of a question mark doesn't necessarily make a question clear, useful, or unambiguous, e.g. see [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). Questions with one just lack this particular smell.

Bad meat is evident either way.

Comment: agree about your last point but *existence of a question mark* is certainly a good start. actually *"Can someone help me?*" is perfectly answerable, though it's probably not the answer they were looking for.

Comment: On the other hand, sometimes it's useful to give an answerer room to expound of all of "What?", "Why?", and "How?" in the same space. Questions can be too broad, but they can also be too narrow. Just because a more specific question would be acceptable doesn't mean that it would be superior, nor that a more vague question would be disallowed.

Comment: @MarkAmery if they're after all three then asking all three is great. Without any a lot of answers default to just "how" which can be less satisfying (unless you just don't care about the guts of a problem and simply want it gone.) Really good answers will go above and beyond in any case, but this is more about what a question will tend to attract and whether it'll cover what you need.