# How is 'Please help me' acceptable in a question and 'I need help' refused

Tags: discussion, specific-question, title

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67037797/i-have-to-map-a-collection-mapstring-liststring-type-please-help-me-with-th) has the following title which is considered acceptable

> I have to map a collection Map<String,List> type .Please help me with the annotations

When I tried to rename it to

> I have to map a collection Map<String,List> type and I need help with the annotations

But it got rejected.

I understand my edit was not ideal, but I don't understand how the original question passed through as it contains a clear "Please help me" word sequence.

Comment: You shouldn't have edited the title this way (thankfully, the system somewhat works). Help pleas have no place either in titles or bodies - we already know the OP needs help because they posted a question. Also, you introduced [a run-on sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Run-on_sentences). Anyways, the current rendition looks ok to me. More on point - you probably know there are some pretty basic quality filters in place. Not sure how the original got through, but the OPs version has a misplaced dot that might've choked the filter.

Comment: @OlegValter Yes I know the edition was not ideal (which I acknowledge in the question too). Indeed I know the filters are in place, which is why I'm surprised the original passed through. In my eyes `Please help me` is one of the first sequence of words I would ban if I were to implement such feature.

Comment: The first title gets rejected as well if there's a space between `.` and `Please`. The title filter is known to not be particularly sophisticated, and so it's not too surprising that it trips up on cases like this.

Comment: Ok so, as @OlegValter was suggesting, the point has caused the filter to miss. Thanks guys. Is there any way this could be improved? Is that something "we" can do or is that a responsibility of the website owners?

Comment: No, there's nothing users can do, other than post a feature-request that the staff may choose to incorporate into the filter.

Comment: @YassinHajaj - I am sure you know, that's more for the benefit of passer-by readers :) Regarding your question, agreed with cigien - not much we can do. You can try a FR, but I am not sure if the chances for the filter being amended are more than 0...

Comment: Whatever you want to say about the title filter, it forced people to think of an actual better title.

Comment: Related: *[Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You try to look for rhyme and reason in the title filter. Don't do that. You don't want to lose your sanity.

In November 2011 this was posted:

[The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944)

and this gem got added by [NullUserException อ_อ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/149052/nulluserexception-%e0%b8%ad-%e0%b8%ad) in  that question:

> <sub>So I can't mention the Halting Problem in the title? – Keith Thompson Nov 1 at 19:05</sub>
>
> <sub>@KeithThompson Maybe it's a "Halting Issue". Or "Need help with Halting". Or the "Halting thing in Computability Theory". – slhck Nov 1 at 19:14</sub>

In the 6 to 8 years that followed 2011 not much, if anything, changed. That observation from 2011 is valid today. There are not much competitors for the worst idea so I'm sure this one is here to stay.