# What should I do when one wants to help a question asker with debugging hints and pointers, but those would be too long for comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Sometimes I find myself wanting to contribute some background information that might help solving a question without actually having a concrete solution at hand. However, this information can be come quite large for a comment and might even contain some example code (not specific to the question, but the topic at large).

In such cases I don't particularly want to write an answer, because it simply isn't. Most of the time it is too big or structure for a comment though.

Are there any guidelines on how to deal with such situations?
Do I write a comment with potential horrible format or a solution that is none? Or do I refrain from contributing at all? (I don't prefer the last one, but I list it for completion.)

Comment: What do you mean by "background information"?

Comment: well e.g. if somebody asks why the compiler doesn't perform a specific optimization on this code, the answer regarding the code is often not trivial to give;
however, information about under what circumstances the optimization is done and fist rules when not is often easier and faster to provide; it doesn't constitute an answer to the original question though

Comment: I'd generally discourage this. In some cases I've had 20-30 lengthy comments back&forth with an OP guiding him through a complicated setup (it wouldn't make sense writing a Q&A since neither problem nor solution can be adequately synthesized or would do future readers much good.) In these cases dropping a comment that isn't for immediate use by an OP won't help future readers much.

Comment: If you want to provide debugging help in comments, and the debugging instructions feel too long,  I'd be surprised that information is not written anywhere else that one could link to.

Comment: @yivi problem is a whole project can break because of 1 or 2 details in the layout. Narrowing it down will take a lot of explanation, and even if you link to 6-8 canonicals along the way the solution will be some localized detail that won't do anyone much good besides the OP.

Comment: @bad_coder comments are meant to help the OP, so they can clarify their question and add relevant information. That's the reason they are treated as ephemeral, they are meant for the OP but not necessarily for future visitors.

Comment: @yivi I'm aware of what comments are for, but there are also 1000's of OP's who got their solution in the comments and having that Q&A hanging around wouldn't have added any value to the repository. In most of those cases it only becomes clear towards the end what the problem was and if it would be worth to compose an answer.

Comment: Write a blog post on your own blog, then post a comment: *if you need tips and tricks how to debug this, see the blog post I wrote [here](https://example.com)*. That is similar to [what we do here](https://idownvotedbecau.se/)

Comment: Alternatively: think of a narrow-scoped question that could have your background info as an answer. Be careful: creating well-received canonicals is hard on SO.

Comment: Some tag wiki's also have canonical guidance in them, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info or https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info

Comment: Just to be clear: Are we talking about helping the OP before their question gets closed, or are we talking about helping the OP in addition to answers? Because huge comment threads usually are an indication that the question lacks details or focus – and should thus be closed.

Comment: I get it, sometimes getting to the extra information that would help solve a problem requires debugging and if the person asking the question is incapable of doing that debugging, the only way out would be personal assistance and mentoring. That is the moment where you have to contain yourself. Someone people need answers, others need schooling. The people who need schooling will need to find that somewhere else. The best you can do is point them to a debugging guide.

Comment: @Gimby some of the *"need schooling people"* you refer to, are leading researches, experienced devs, regular contributors, who run into an undocumented bug, an edge case, that surfaces on SO and is triaged or solved here before being posted on proper channels. In those cases the tag regulars contribute in turn to try and identify the issue, so if you have say the 3 top tag contributors taking interest in such a post they probably know what they're doing.

Comment: @bad_coder I don't care if it's the inventor of the language and three of the co-writers. Take it some place else. There are thousands of other venues on the internet. Move it to GitHub, Discord, Slack, ... heck, even Stack Overflow has a chat implementation they could use. Comments are not the right place.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah, but a core dev adds more value and insight in 1 comment than your entire meta punditry :P (I do read several core devs who are SO regulars on a daily basis.)

Comment: @bad_coder And that's a totally fair assessment of my relative meta worth :). Nonetheless, the point stands. Stack Overflow can't be a site for everything about development and I would hate it if it tried. Imagine if SO tried to be "the Facebook of developers" and started running "apps" and "games".

Comment: @Gimby that's obviously not true, otherwise 5k, 10k, 25k reps wouldn't ask questions and never get stuck. Besides, lots of debugging questions went on to become successful SO threads. (Taking several answers by different users to provide a complete picture.)

Comment: I think the question comes down to, what are we here for?  Are we trying to (1) build a high-quality database of good questions and answers, or are we trying to (2) help people out with their problems?  The original goal, which some people are still trying to uphold, was (1).  But there are plenty of people who are much more interested in (2).  (And I have no idea what the new owners would say the real goal is now.)

Comment: @SteveSummit that's a false dichotomy, you can help people with a high quality library of practical programming questions. Like a Q&A about how to debug a particular issue. The problem is when people close questions that need to follow this as duplicate of the guide!

Comment: @Braiam It's a false dichotomy only if you agree that questions that don't fit SO's format have no place here and are being comprehensively discouraged.  But these days, I submit that a large percentage (perhaps even a majority) of questions don't fit SO's format: they're either dupes, or "Help me out".  (And the posters are being helped out, rightly or wrongly.)

Comment: I just want to add that there are questions asking for help on how to debug. An answer explaining why their previous debug attempts were not successful and how to debug better IMHO is a valid answer.

Comment: @SteveSummit now your argument goes from a false dichotomy to a false premise.

Comment: @bad_coder Let me be more explicit, then.  Even though the original goal of SO was (1) building a database of high-quality answers to a certain kind of question, plenty of people today evidently have no interest in that goal.  Plenty of people love to (2) help OP's with their questions, even if those questions aren't the "certain kind" that SO was intended for, and even if the help ends up taking the form of a long series of comments, and no upvotable answer at all.  In fact, so many people are doing (2) today that I honestly wonder whether the old goal of (1) is really applicable any more.

Comment: The dichotomy I set up between (1) and (2) was in response to several comments in this thread which seemed to say, "SO is for a certain kind of question and nobody -- nobody! -- should be asking other kinds, or abusing the comments section by trying to 'help' people with those other kinds.  Those other kinds of questions should be on other sites dedicated to that kind of help." But arguments like this make sense to me iff (1) is still truly in effect.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If it is too long for a comment and not suitable for an answer...

**Do not put it into either comments or answer.**

There are other means available to put information and communicate. Stack Overflow itself offers [a chat system](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) and allows for comments to link to external resources, such as gists or pastebins for formatted content. Some people might also be open for third-party means of communication.

But ultimately, your goal should be to keep out of the Q&A formula whatever does not fit into the Q&A formula.

Comment: While the chat system itself is ideal for such inquiries, its relationship to the main site is not; you can't "move to chat" at will (you have to be invited, a process that seems random at best), and when you do, it doesn't actually move the conversation to chat; it leaves all of the original comments intact. In addition, chat offers none of the other benefits of posting answers, such as voting, moderation and clarifying comments about the answer itself.

Comment: @RobertHarvey These points are all valid for content that should be in comments or answers. The content alluded to in the question should not.

Comment: An observation that does nothing about the brokenness of "move to chat."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Don't let the good be the enemy of good enough. These users need one-on-one and someone is willing to provide it. Let them use it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: your comments about the deficiencies of the chat system are accurate. But, are they relevant? What is your goal in sharing those comments? If you are arguing that this answer is incorrect _because_ of those deficiencies, I'd say you're mistaken. That the chat system needs improvements isn't justification to misuse the rest of the site features. If you're not arguing that this answer is incorrect, then your comments, however accurate, seem not to offer anything that's actually relevant in terms of clarifying or critiquing this answer. It comes across as more a rant, than anything

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I don't particularly care about how my comments come across.  What I do care about is how blasé these issues seem to everyone, this being a prime example.  I've complained about these deficiencies for years, but nothing ever happens.  Y'all are arguing for an approach that uses a broken system; how does that make sense?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: _"I don't particularly care about how my comments come across"_ -- then why bother posting the comment in the first place? _"I've complained about these deficiencies for years, but nothing ever happens"_ -- what makes you think that posting a comment under this answer is going to change that? Please remember that comments, even on Meta, are for requesting clarification or more information from the author, and on Meta _sometimes_ for discussing the immediate issue at hand (an exception from the non-Meta rules). Posting comments that have nothing at all to do with the ...

Comment: ... question or answer you've commented on is pointless and just makes it that much harder to follow whatever relevant conversation is present.

Comment: Already spent too much time on this, but thanks for the observations.  Frankly I'm a little baffled.  Y'all seem more intent on following what you consider the "rules" than making things better.

Comment: I tend to share @Robert's sentiments about following perceived rules as opposed to making things better. But I go a little different direction after that. My question would be, **why can't you just put enough gloss on the information to make it suitable for posting as an answer?** I'd much rather have this posted as an answer, for a variety of reasons, than hidden in chat or not posted at all. There is no rule that answers need to be 100% complete; they just need to be relevant *attempts* to provide a solution.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this approach des make a lot of sense; using pastebin and co to communicate stuff that doesn't really fit the Q&A seems quite reasonable; thx :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey \@CodyGray I am frankly rather irritated that you attribute this to following the rules and not wanting to make things better. If things don't fit, they don't fit. If Chat and links are available as alternatives, they are available as alternatives. If people don't feel like posting an answer, they don't feel like posting an answer. If people don't feel like raging against chat for the umpteenth time, perhaps, just perhaps, they aren't rule abiding sheeples but just sick of all the bickering.

Comment: If you want people to use this solution, it should be at least somewhat obvious how to use it. Since it is NOT obvious how to use the chat system, I deduce that not many people will use this solution. (That is to say, if people don't use the chat system, perhaps they are not rule-breaking mavericks, but just can't figure out how to. They may not even realize that it exists or that it is a possibility to start chatting outside of some magic that comes along and starts a chat session when there are too many comments.)

Comment: What should be obvious is that **there are other sites besides Stack Overflow** on the internet, some of which actually provide better chat/message board functionality than Stack Overflow, which was never meant as either a chat or message board platform. Some of these sites are actually devoted to the very topics about which people wish to chat and/or message. Can it be challenging to find one that all users share in common that works well? Sure! That's what we call opportunity people! Stack Overflow provides an API; someone create a site that provides great chat and links with SO, quick! :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey as a complete aside, I think you're using "blasé" wrongly. Everyone may have a blasé attitude to the issues, but the issues themselves are not (and cannot seem to be) blasé. Alternatively, perhaps the issues seem trivial or insignificant to everyone.

Answer (score 11):

If you have information that would prevent the question from being closed or even make it easier to answer, you can always edit the question. Remove unnecessary parts, or add some more information. However, if you want to provide debugging steps for the author then it's best to close the question and optionally link in comments to some helpful resources that explain how to debug this kind of problem.

Don't waste time on questions that are unclear. It's not your job to help the question author improve the question. Only invest time if you think that the improved question will help other people with similar issues. In all other cases, vote to close, downvote, and move on.

Answer (score 0):

You can for every point add another comment.

It is common enough, but as always comments can be deleted very quickly.

Also you can offer the user a chat, where you can in one on one conversation get more information or give tips.

After that you can formulate an answer, or add the new gathered information from the chat to the question.

Comment: What do you mean by *"you can in one on one"* (seems incomprehensible - missing word(s)?)?

Comment: a chat and in a one on one conversation but as it is a chat the conversation is implicit

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Just an unconventional word order, I'm guessing. Might be clearer with added punctuation: *…where you can, in one-on-one conversation, get more information or…*

Comment: "i don't have the answer, but i think u should try this method (of looking at the problem).. " that should count, right? | Apparently SO is does not have that facility (like sidenote/troubleshooting-hint-tag) Even if you actually want to take a vote.. u have to do it in Q&A format.. | the pro : solid codebase/dbase , the cons : (we arrive at this page.. ) "-_-

Comment: my sentences are logical correct, and still you can improve them i always can revet it back

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether the OP asked a clear question or not. If they didn't, downvote and vote to close as "unclear" or "needs debugging details." Stack Overflow is for specific questions and answers, not general advice and tips.

It also depends on how comprehensive your advice is. If it's comprehensive enough to at least be a [partial answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), it *might* be valid to post it as an answer. (I do recognize that that point could be controversial, though).

There are also several canonical Q&As you could use as dupe targets (or point the OP to in comments), such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) on how to use a debugger or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) on how to use stack traces. Many error messages, such as the infamous "Unfortunately MyApp has stopped" in Android, have their own [canonical dupe targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) too.

Also see: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score -10):

Refrain from contributing at all.

If an asker isn't able or willing to provide the detail required to answer their question, that's not your problem. Because it's not your problem, don't waste your time trying to pry those details from the asker, whether it's in comments or chat or whatever.

If you really enjoy that kind of thing, reddit or other forums are a far more suitable format for it.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question tbh; the question is not about the askers will or ability to provide detail but on enhancing information that the asker might simply not know or know how to obtain...