# Help understanding a triage review queue suspension

Tags: discussion, triage, review-suspension

Today I saw in my inbox that I've been suspended from the review queue for two days in the recent past, due to "incorrectly handling" [this triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/30990000).

Screenshot of the post:

[image: screenshot of post]

[Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70988811/timeline):

[image: Screenshot of timeline]

I'm not really sure what I did wrong, really. When I click the link it says the general consensus was that this post "Looks OK", and that's what I also voted. I also left a comment in answer to another comment, to suggest that it maybe should be an answer instead. I see the entire question is deleted now.

Was I suspended for leaving the comment? Or was everyone who voted "Looks OK" suspended? Was I manually suspended by a moderator? I've read the FAQs and I'm not really sure what exactly happened.

Comment: Maybe I'm the only one, but that question most assuredly does not "Look OK". There's no minimal, reproducible example on it, no evidence of an attempt (which is technically not required but is indicative of an okay question). There's just a "CSS is hard. Figure this out for me. Oh, also do these other things for me too" question.

Comment: I don't have 10K rep so can't see the post, but the fact that the post was deleted is usually pretty strong evidence that it does not look OK.

Comment: @pppery The screenshot just edited in seems to suggest it was automatically deleted by the Roomba. It's just a bot; it cannot determine the exact quality of the post and can only go off some signals (such as two downvotes).

Comment: Moot now, but I disagree; the fact that a post becomes roomba-able for any reason other than the 365-day deletion means that someone downvoted it (two peole in this case), hence it is not OK. Moderators presumably won't suspend people for mistakes more than one year old, so a triage review suspension can't be based on a 365-day roomba and my original logic holds.

Comment: @gparyani Yes, it was deleted by Roomba. It's unclear exactly what triggered the review suspension though.

Comment: Moving on to the specific question, it's a clear duplicate of [Select every Nth element in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3462298/3750257). I'm not sure to what extent Triage reviewers are required to search for duplicates, but just looking at the question made me think "this **has** to have been asked before"

Comment: Likely relevant: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Looks ok? At a *minimum* it needed an edit: there is a bunch of noise (basically the whole part of the question starting with examples). Not to mention it is also a mega-dupe of `nth-child` (as pppery rightfully mentioned). It is anything *but* looks ok.

Comment: @pppery That's an interesting question arising: are reviewers are required/expected to consider duplicates in triage?

Comment: @skomisa according to the list of actions available for a triage review, no, they are not expected to. One could argue that a post may "need author edit" to clarify it is not a duplicate, but that is certainly not the case for the post in question - there is simply no way it is not a dupe. Pointing out it is a mega-dupe is somewhat of an off-note (at least regarding my comment, can't speak for pppery).

Comment: There is a "flag" option, so how should they make a solid decision that it is not flagable when they don't check for dupes? But I've also noticed in past review queue questions here on meta that some people are quite surprised that they are actually excpected to do review in those queues and not just skim over the question with half an eye.

Comment: @pppery *"the fact that a post becomes roomba-able for any reason other than the 365-day deletion means that someone downvoted it (two peole in this case), hence it is not OK"* - The fact that it received no upvotes to counter the downvotes is the full clue to the truth, two downvotes on their own are only a very weak signal.

Comment: You reviewed the question on Feb 6, did you get suspended only now? Suspensions usually occur when reaching a certain threshold of failed audits, however, your name appears on the reviewer's list, which means this question was not an audit, at least not for you.

Comment: If the question is "Can anyone help?", the post has issues.