# How can I improve my question about an import issue in TypeScript?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, quality-improvement

I'm facing an issue when importing third-party packages that have external type packages like @types/packageName.
Example: UUID, aws-lambda

I wrote my question with details including app structure and step by step commands to regenerate the issue. Is there something else that I'm missing to describe my issue efficiently?

Here is that question post: [On converting ES5 require to ES6 import get the typescript error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74873870/on-converting-es5-require-to-es6-import-get-the-typescript-error)

How can I improve it further to get an answer?

Comment: Some parts of the question are not well formatted. Look out for the difference between simple code expressions \` and code blocks (\`\`\`), and don't put things which are not code inside them.

Comment: My second concern about the question is that there is probably a good duplicate target somewhere. Missing type definitions are a common issue when the main package does not include them. Did you also not try the suggestion in the error message?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @E_net4thecommentflagger.
The question has been updated with proper formatting.
The question is not about type definitions, but about the nested project structure that doesn't detect type definitions.
The question has been updated and I've also added more information that I had on hand

Comment: Question looks a lot better now, especially steps to reproduce. These types of questions can be tricky questions and basically impossible without seeing this step by step. The gold standard is a stackblitz / github repo - this almost guarantees an answer

Comment: You might add an update to mention that you have [now self-answered the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74917456/2985643) under discussion. Also, while your question looks good now, you should also accept the answer that you posted because accepted answers are more helpful for the community.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good on you for seeking feedback on how to improve!

I looked at revision 6 and made some spacing touchups so it's now at revision 7 as I write this. I tried to make your directory tree diagrams cleaner, but they were a bit confusing before (I'm assuming with some artifacts of simplifying), so I don't actually know if I did it 100% correctly. Please check and correct if I made a mistake.

#### Is it an error or is it a warning?

I haven't written TS in a while, but in my memory, missing types for a dependency import is just a warning- not an error.

If it's a warning, make sure to use the right terminology.

#### Keep Non-Code out of Code-Blocks

I spy the following line in the middle of one of your code blocks:

> add following json to tsconfig.json file:

If it's not code, don't put it in a code block.

#### Disambiguate your Title

I would strongly suggest to include part of the error message in the title (the part that you would search for in a web search engine). It is an essential disambiguating component of your question. For more info on this guidance, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which instructs on how to write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title.

Here's a title I might have written:

> TypeScript error: "Could not find a declaration file for module 'uuid'" when converting require to ES6 import

I'm not aware of `require` being an ECMAScript thing. I thought it was just a NodeJS thing, so I removed the "ES5 require" from the title as I thought it could be conceptually confusing and wasn't a necessary detail. But perhaps I'm wrong about that.

#### Ask a Question!

I'd suggest ending your question post by actually asking a question. There are two good reasons:

1. For any answerers who are skimming posts, it really helps them know what the *actual question* is.
2. For google, it adds to the searchability of the content, so that people in the future who have a similar problem have a better chance of finding this post if they ask a similar question.

For similar expanded guidance, see [this answer to "Why is 'Can someone help me?' not an actual question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541).

I tend to suggest people to write generic questions like "Why is this happening, and how can the problem be fixed?", but you can go further and write something less generic (Why `<the problem>`, and how can it be fixed?)

#### Technical Questions for you

Here's a comment I made under your post asking for some details on technical points:

> In your tsconfig.json, why do you still have "`"module": "commonjs"`" if you are trying to change to ECMAScript imports? Shouldn't it be ["module": "ES6"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module)? Also, this seems like a strange setup. Can you give a brief explanation of why you put dependencies in `:/dependencies/nodejs/node_modules` instead of `:/node_modules`? Please [edit].

Comment: Sorry for hijacking the comments on this answer. I've just realised that I've partly undone your edits on three questions ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/422272/revisions), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/422277/revisions), and [the question we're on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/422315/revisions)) as you've edited them to put post IDs into the titles.

Comment: I removed the post IDs because the questions already had links to the posts in the questions, so I couldn't see the reasoning behind adding them in the first place - the only reason that I could think of for adding the post ID would be to make it possible to search for discussions about a specific post on Meta (which is probably unlikely) - if it is, often users will post a comment on the post saying something like "*This post is being discussed on Meta Stack Overflow*" or something similar.

Comment: "If it's not code, don't put it in a code block." — I'd say there's a bit more nuance than never doing it, but it's certainly a good general rule, and is applicable to this case.

Comment: "I'm not aware of `require` being an ECMAScript thing. I thought it was just a NodeJS thing" – Technically, it's a [CommonJS](https://commonjs.org/) thing (formerly known as ServerJS), but Node.JS is by far the most well-known implementation.