# How can I deal with this old useful question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Some time ago, I was looking at developing on PlayStation. The only post I found was [Sony PS4 app development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39018320/10952503) and I want to talk about this one specially.

The questions seems:

- **Opinion based**. It literally asks for "any advice, hint or whatever if appreciated"
- **Not a code problem** as he didn't write code yet
- **Having an outdated answer**, as I tried those, but links are no longer working or not up-to-date

But also:

- A **useful question** that interests people. We can see it has views and upvotes.
- Asking for **help about code environment** as Java users will ask with [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) or [intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij)
- Received answer from some people, so **can be answered**

I don't really know if the post is at a good place. If not, where should it go?

Also, if I want to ask question with similar objective (but not similar context), should I create it in Stack Overflow? Or in another website of SE?

Comment: This seems to tick all of "lacks details" (it's entirely unclear what specific, practical problem they have), "needs focus" (asking both the (vague) 'it possible or not' and separate licensing issue), "opinion-based" (just look at the answers offering wildly different info the authors felt were useful). That there is no code, that answers are outdated, that someone found it useful, that the general topic may be on-topic, or that someone managed to put things into the answer box don't change that.

Comment: Yes, you're right @MisterMiyagi (and thanks for the comment on the main post). But do you think it's asked on good website of SE network ?

Comment: If I type "sony playstation 4 development" into Google, one of the commonly asked questions Google comes back with is "how much does a dev kit cost?". 2.5k, apparently. I assume you would want to develop for PS5 now, so... Point is that there is no reason you wouldn't know you need a dev kit. If you are looking for ways to do it without needing that pricy dev kit... the search term you are looking for is "homebrew".

Comment: "*The questions seems:*" doesn't make sense grammatically (Sing/Plur), + only 1 Dot for the 6 Bullet-Points, and I "see" some "*ask question*" somewhere further from a quick scan (also not correct grammatically), I didn't read further after the "annoying"/confusing "*The questions seems:*" Sentence, you lose (some of) your "Audience" if you can't spell-check your Posts, just saying... :idea: (Just Feedback, I didn't vote.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Asking for **help about code environment** as Java users will ask with [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) or [intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij)

I see no evidence of this in the text of the question. No particular environment is mentioned; OP simply wants to develop for PS4, with no idea of what that entails, or indeed of *whether any particular IDE is required*, officially supported, provided along with the official dev tools, etc. etc. etc.

> A **useful question** that interests people. We can see it has views and upvotes.

> Received answer from some people, so **can be answered**

These things can be just as easily said about, say, the [the food safety canonical on cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670). They also are **completely and utterly irrelevant** as long as the question is unsuitable for other reasons.

I honestly would have voted to close as "not about programming". For a question to be about "a specific programming problem or software algorithm", OP needs to either have explained a problem and asked about algorithmic analysis or some language-agnostic programming concept, or (the much more common case) **identified a specific programming language** in which the code either is or will be written. To be about "software tools commonly used by programmers", similarly, OP needs to have a **specific tool in mind already**, and a specific problem **related to that tool**.

> Also, if I want to ask question with similar objective (but not similar context), should I create it in Stack Overflow? Or in another website of SE?

Anywhere on SE, you would still need to refine the question considerably. Other SE sites are **not discussion fora** any more than Stack Overflow is - the Q&A format is not intended for this kind of open-ended query. "any advice, hint or whatever if appreciated." is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) and "Needs More Focus" is a network-wide closure reason rather than a community-specific one. The question "is this possible" is unclear - **what possible obstacle** does OP have in mind? Is this about whether people are legally allowed to do this? Whether a programming language exists for the purpose? Something else? The *implied* question is "what do I need to know in order to begin development?", which, again, is far too open-ended. The standard reminder about [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) also seems apropos here.