# Any way to fight downvotes spam?

Tags: feature-request, downvotes

Just noticed that someone downvoted a question and all 5 answers which all are basically correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564033/js-object-change-string-to-number/76564085

Is there any action that can be taken against such behavior?
If no, I would suggest at least revealing who downvoted. In that case the spam's author could be seen and reported...

Comment: There is a comment under your question which states that the example doesn't make sense. I can't judge if this is correct, but it certainly could be a valid reason to downvote.

Comment: Sure, throw stones on the downvoters, this will surely help.

Comment: 2) You changed the question after most of the answers had been added. Now they look like they don't match the question which may also lead to downvotes. Please rollback your last edit; edits on questions should never invalidate existing answers.

Comment: Correct answers are not exempt from receiving downvotes. The main criteria for downvoting is the post being considered "not useful". So you have not fully demonstrated why the voting patterns are a problem here.

Comment: "Spam" has a very specific meaning. Calling everything you disagree with "spam" interferes with effective communication. Your complaint here is more accurately phrased as, "I disagree with some downvotes", which is much less actionable and, I hope, reveals the folly inherent in this feature request.

Comment: Nice find! Hadn’t I been on strike, I’d have downvoted it all, too!

Comment: Well, it's now deleted. Ironically, (hypocritically) 2 of the delete-votes are from high rep users that answered it, after I called them out on it...

Comment: your P.S. is a different question. please avoid asking 2 unrelated questions at once

Comment: "all 5 answers which all are basically correct" - Basically "correct" might not be "technically correct" or "helpful to the community", I often find answers that are "basically correct" are not actually all that helpful. The fact the question was deleted suggested the question had a major problem, which means, users decided to answer a low quality question which often means their answers would be low quality also. **It seems like low quality contributions were downvotes which is exactly what should be happening.** If you found those contributions helpful you should upvote them, I didn't.

Comment: Re *"downvotes spam"*: Sample of other titles: *[People who downvote all answers on a post because the question is low quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250135/)* and *[Is the act of downvoting all answers for a question ascribed to serial voting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389087/is-the-act-of-downvoting-all-answers-for-a-question-ascribed-to-serial-voting)*

Comment: This example suggests Stack Overflow *is* a help desk. There was not even an *attempt* to find the duplicate in the first 1 1/2 hour.

Answer (score 32):

I'm sorry to say, but the question and answers just aren't good.

1. Don't draw attention to bad questions on Meta. The [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) might just result in more downvotes.
2. The question itself is just yet another extremely simple *"I want to map a property on an array of objects"* question. There's tons of dupes out there for it. That alone is plenty of reason to downvote the question.
3. The answers are, *without exception*, ***bad***:

   - One has broken formatting
   - One is extremely overcomplicated by a high reputation rep "hunter" that always overcomplicates anything they answer, and doesn't care about closing duplicates
   - Another high rep user posted an okay answer instead of closing it as a dupe
   - A new user actually posted a proper answer, but failed to include any explanation. I'd be tempted to be lenient on that one as he's new, but it's still an answer to an extremely common duplicate.
   - The last one, you, attempted used JSON and a regex replace(?!!!?!) to parse integers. Aside from that just not even working reliably, that's a horrible approach.

So, there's plenty of reason to downvote each and every contribution there.

Comment: The "other high rep user" responded to the dupe problem with "We all answered it. Relax" when indicated that it was a dupe. There are too many of these rep hunters that think they are in the right on SO. They are not if we want SO to be a KB where people search before asking a question.

Comment: There's a couple of very active ones that try to answer anything and everything regarding JavaScript, especially when array manipulation is concerned. And when called out on it, they just delete the answer and answer the next one. It's so frustrating to see the same old dupes being answered time and time again.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-onstrike [the incentives are completely broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/_/387550), as are the UI affordances. People treat Stack Overflow as if it were something completely different from what it's intended to be, because *it looks and feels like that other thing* on a technical level and because of the inertia of others who are comfortable with that wrong interpretation.

Answer (score 21):

> Is there any action that can be taken against such behavior?

Why would there be? These downvotes were correct, and in fact praise-worthy.

> If no, I would suggest at least revealing who downvoted.

[Absolutely not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/). This is perhaps the single-most requested feature on Meta, and it will be roundly rejected every time - because it completely misses the point.

> In that case the spam's author could be seen and reported...

There is nothing to report - again, this is not only perfectly acceptable use of the site, but in fact laudable.

It is also not "spam", as far as we are concerned. We are extremely concerned with preventing people from abusing the site to post ads for goods and services. However, generally speaking, "doing the same thing a lot" is only bad if the thing itself is bad.

---

I understand that all of this must seem counterintuitive to you. This is because you have the same complete misunderstanding about **what Stack Overflow is** that most new users (and even quite a few established ones) do.

- Stack Overflow is **not social media**; as such, there is no expectation to have a positive-by-default attitude, as we are judging **content, not authors**.
- Stack Overflow is **not a help desk**; questions need to be **actually questions, not** a code dump followed by ["help me please"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), and when the underlying question is something that has been addressed before, we close it as a duplicate. (We *do not care* that OP phrased things differently or has slightly different practical requirements; what matters is the *underlying question* and the *answers to that question*.)
- The purpose of questions on Stack Overflow is **not to solve the issue OP is encountering**, but instead to **build a high-quality, searchable Q&A library**. This requires questions to be properly focused on a single problem, and thus searchable. High-quality answers **require high-quality questions**; without that, they can at best be high-quality *lecture material*, which is not what we offer here. Answers to questions that don't meet site standards are *inherently not useful and even counter-productive* (as they interfere with the process of improving salvageable questions and also with the process of deleting hopeless ones). For all I know (because I did not try the code), maybe OP had a perfectly fine approach to the problem, and failed only because the code tries to fix the `el` key of the objects but should actually work with the `y` key instead (we would consider this a typo).
- All the answers shown here are effectively code-only; they say almost nothing about how they approach the problem, how to understand the code, what was wrong with the original approach (which, granted, is hard to do since OP *didn't describe what went wrong* - this is part of why high-quality questions are so important!) or anything else. **Simply being "correct" as judged by OP is nowhere near sufficient**.