# Why are 'too localized' questions not welcome?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Why does the pattern to reveal buttons stops at the first iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78160455/why-does-the-pattern-to-reveal-buttons-stops-at-the-first-iteration)

A user commented that they’re going to vote to close it because it was 'too localized'. Does that mean that if a question is too specific on one code, in a way that it is hard to apply the same logic to other code, it isn't allowed? If so, then if someone has a too specific code problem, what should he/she do? Go ask ChatGPT?

Comment: No idea what they meant by "too localized" but at 350 lines of code this desperately needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of a code dump.

Comment: I was looking for some other delphi questions before making my own, when I saw some users asking for more parts of the code to give more context, so that made me confused on what do I would need to add on my question

Comment: [Where did too localized go](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252034/where-did-too-localized-go) . People have trouble letting go of labels they're used to. As a more recent example, people still keep referring to "too broad" even though it no longer exists as a close reason. Unfortunate because the more time passes, the more communication errors it causes.

Comment: @Gimby on your latter example, 'too broad' simply got renamed to 'needs more focus', but it's still the same reason. 'too localized' as a reason was entirely replaced with 'not reproducible', which is not the same (although there is a lot of overlap). So I can see (and I still do) people still using 'too broad' colloquially, but there's not really an excuse for someone using 'too localized' anymore. It's equally as unacceptable as saying "I'm closing this question because it's not a real question" ('not a real question' as a close reason went away a long time ago, too).

Comment: @TylerH doesn't matter. It is now the wrong name for it, not present in the list of close reasons. So people who join the site now will go "too broad, wut?"

Comment: I cleared the close vote. "Too localized" isn't a valid close reason. If the question is off-topic because of some other issue (lacking clarity, not reproducible, etc.), it can be closed as such. Otherwise, it's on-topic. Questions that are on-topic but not useful should be downvoted, not closed.

Comment: @Gimby I was talking about colloquial use (e.g. in chat). Users casting such close votes will still choose "needs focus" today and that's still what end users/askers will see. There's no issue there.

Answer (score 43):

As @Gimby [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429478/why-too-localized-questions-are-not-welcome?cb=1#comment990742_429478), *too localized* was an old close reason that no longer exists. (See [Where did "too localized" go?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252034/290085))

The rationale behind *too localized* was that the question is too tied to the particulars of your situation to be of general interest.  In your case, you have an excessively long dump of code rather than a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and so the party tossing around the *too localized* label is saying that it's likely that the solution is going to be too tied to your code and unlikely to help anyone else – *too local* to your particular situation.

There are two major schools of thought as to whether such questions are good for the site:

1. **Bad**: The site is mostly about accumulating Q/A useful to future readers, therefore *too localized* questions have little merit.
2. **Good**: The site is mostly about helping individuals, therefore no question can be *too localized*.

I happen to believe #1 is best but wanted to be clear that #2 has its supporters too.

Comment: The problem is that people are bad at judging what's "too localized".  You never know what a search engine is going to key off.

Comment: @MarkRansom: True, and I think you expressed the need to balance specificity and generality well [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428108/290085).

Comment: You expressed a preference for viewpoint #1 so I felt it was worth responding to.  I wasn't singling out any group as being worse at judging, just recognizing the more general difficulty of knowing what others will find useful in the future.

Comment: Thanks for digging up that recent post of mine, it's really nice to know that people actually read your stuff!

Comment: "The site is mostly about helping individuals" - yes there will always be people who use the site as they please, not as intended. Luckily there is now the discussions feature, that should open up some wiggle room.

Comment: I believe that we only help the community by helping individuals, so the two things don't conflict. The problem with this kind of "code dump" problem is that the user is typically having trouble isolating the code that causes the trouble, which may be due to their general lack of programming skill. What do we do about unskilled users? We can't ignore them, surely?

Comment: "I believe that we only help the community by helping individuals ..." - The key is >which< individuals we help.

Comment: "What do we do about unskilled users?" - wasn't that the idea behind [the popular "staging ground" initiative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/staging-ground)? To give novice users (and also, users with poor English) a way to post well-intentioned but flawed questions and learn the ropes from those experienced users who like onboarding, without clogging the feeds of the users who don't? Unfortunately [it was dropped](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427363/568458) in favour of something something AI something

Answer (score 34):

"Too localized" is an old close reason that is no longer [used](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/). A lot of old site regulars have a reasonably good intuition for what questions do or don't belong on Stack Overflow, but don't have an up-to-date understanding of how to map problems to closure reasons. (This is an understatement; the "too localized" close reason was removed many years ago.)

**The [point of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770)**, as described in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), **is to get away from the traditional model of a discussion forum** where you can submit a personalized request for help with a code project. It's intended to be somewhere that a given question only needs to be answered once, and then other people with the same question can be referred there.

For this to work, people who have the question [need to do the work first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to understand **what the question actually is**. In other words: if you are trying to figure out a problem in your existing code, it's your responsibility before posting to:

- **Understand**, step by step, **what you intend** for the existing code to do and how you intend for it to work;
- Carefully **check**, step by step, **what is actually happening** as the code runs, and see where it does something different from your expectation;
- Isolate *one* such instance of the code doing something wrong, and **set up [minimal framing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** for that part of the code, so that you can **demonstrate** the problem *directly* and so that others can **reproduce** it directly;
- **Ask a question about** that example - for example, "why doesn't `foo` become `1`?" (you should be able to explain clearly why you think `foo` should become `1` after the code has run), or "why does this error occur?", or "where does the file need to be in order for it to be found by this code?". (Alternately, at this point you might decide that you want to ask a "how do I do this?" question instead. In this case, we need a clear specification for "this"; your expected input and output from the previous steps will get you a large part of the way there.)

In other words: we don't provide a [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) service; we don't want to look at hundreds of lines of code and find the problem for you. We also don't solve problems - we [cannot "help" you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) - we **answer questions**.

If, after finding the problem, you decide that you don't have a question to ask about it, **great!** In many of these cases, **Stack Overflow has already helped you**:

- By following this process to form a proper question, you end up with **the ability to search existing questions** on Stack Overflow. Because the *previous* person with the same problem followed these steps, the Q&A you find will be useful to *you as well*, and not just that person - because the problem has been extracted, and matches what you're looking for.
- By following this process to form a proper question, **maybe you realize you can already answer it**. If it turns out that you just mis-typed something, or misunderstood something about the problem specification, etc., then there's nothing more to do. But if you discovered some interesting *concept* underlying the problem, and you don't already see a Q&A about it, [you can ask and answer the question yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and help many other people later who didn't have your special insight.
- By following this process to form a proper question, maybe you're still completely stuck. Every step you can think of breaking the code down into does exactly what you expect, it all connects together properly, but somehow you still get a wrong result. **In this case, you don't have a question about programming; you have a question about logic** - and the answer can probably only be found within yourself. There's no way that anyone else can properly explain to you why following your steps doesn't get to the right result, because there's no way that anyone else can understand why you think those steps *should* get to the right result.

> Does that mean that if a question is too specific on one code, in a way that it is hard to apply the same logic to other code, it isn't allowed?

This is the wrong mindset. **The question is basically never actually "specific to" the code** - unless you made a typo or your logic doesn't make sense. But your question can either "*need debugging details*" or "*need more focus*" - because you either aren't showing the *right part of* the code, or haven't provided the *necessary context for* that code, or both. When you have a proper example that avoids those problems, trivial details like what variable names you used simply won't matter any more. By extracting the part of the code structure that actually causes the problem, you're left with something that *necessarily* applies to other code.

> ...go ask chatGPT?

You are more than welcome to ask ChatGPT - *off-site* - for help with anything. **We assume no responsibility for what happens**. It very often "hallucinates" and does not have anything like a proper understanding of its own output, or logic or reasoning skills. **Sometimes ChatGPT offers suggestions that are not only wrong, but potentially dangerous** (i.e., by introducing a security flaw into your code). But it does, in a large fraction of cases, do a very good job as a search engine that can also synthesize and reformat the results. Because of its pattern-matching, it might be able to "find the bug" for you. At the very least, if ChatGPT's answer focuses on a specific part of your code, you might start by trying to test that part in isolation.

If you find that ChatGPT's answer directly solves your problem, that's also just fine. There's a good chance in this case, as well, that **Stack Overflow has already helped you** - because a lot of Stack Overflow content can be found in the training data.

Comment: As a specific hint for questions about GUI programs: you should first try to figure out whether the problem is in the code that creates the GUI, or in the underlying logic that runs when you click the buttons / input text / etc.

Comment: (Cheerfully:) I have to have a sit down now after the dizzying whirlwind of your hallmark Little Orphan Annie typography. Hmm ... where's the "Too Emphasized" checkbox?

Comment: *[Little Orphan Annie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Orphan_Annie)*. [Sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sunday24.jpg). ChatGPT does actually help a little bit in this case.

Comment: As a test, a friend and I posed ChatGPT some questions about old pre-internet video games (read: Commodore Amiga era). The more obscure games which have little known information about them except for what you might have found in a snippet in a magazine or in an interview. The bot did manage to spew out quite a sizeable amount of data on the games. Most of it pretty wrong, but it sounded very plausible. That's just the thing... it is programmed to answer, so it did the paper-shredder-snippet-gluing thing. ChatGPT is a new toy. People who can't resist new toys are a danger to themselves.

Comment: The general issue here is: what is the minimum level of programming knowledge and skill required of those who ask questions here?  You are setting the bar pretty high. I don't like turning the "copy and paste coders" away; I prefer to give them something that helps them up the learning curve.

Comment: @MichaelKay the bar for asking questions IS high. Now higher than ever since the site has had a good 15 years to fill up the tank. The bar for finding answers is non-existent. Just ask Google or Bing, they'll come to you. Frankly I think the site can do with a summer of abstinence. No new questions, only polishing of existing ones. Make it easier to find existing answers.

Comment: @MichaelKay *programming* knowledge? **Pretty well zero**; for example questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163) are excellent. *debugging* skill? **Fairly standard - any beginner can learn** to attempt the process that I laid out, including Eric Lippert's linked advice. Willingness and ability to *apply* that debugging skill, follow the standard steps, think carefully about what one really wants or needs to know, look through existing Q&A, and formulate the question in English? **Extremely high, yes**.

Comment: When I look through the questions I've saved for reference to close others as duplicates, I'm struck by how *almost all* of them are either how-to questions, or questions about what someone else's code means or why one would write it. Very few are questions about fixing programming gotchas, and many of those would be written in a very different way today (but are either historical-locked or otherwise difficult to change due to all the old answers).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel By "programming knowledge" I didn't mean knowing what particular constructs in a particular language mean, I meant skill in the craft of programming and debugging.

Comment: I think that the debugging skills I describe are fundamental and that even relatively novice programmers ought to have them. They're also not as tightly related to programming as one might think. The same *logical process* can apply for any self-starting learner in any discipline, even physical ones.

Comment: Such a shame that I can upvote this only once.

Answer (score 13):

"Too localized" is not an official close reason. I'm not sure what the comment meant, since highly focused questions are usually encouraged. Also, it was only a single close-vote and down-vote, and your question might yet have been answered if left open.

To me, your question looks to be "why am I experiencing a stack overflow error with this code", and so there may be a duplicate for it.

If it were my question, I'd consider re-opening it, and then posting a comment to the person who made the original comment and close vote, asking for clarification, and asking for meta references for their close-vote reasoning.

Comment: Will do. About the 'stack overflow', in the end i've managed to solve my problem, the stack overflow was cause by bad code, while the problem itself was caused by bad logic.

Comment: "Too localized" **was** an official close reason in the past, so this doesn't apply to question which were closed as such in the past (with the real close reason "Too localized", not a custom close comment of too localized).

Comment: Sorry, "Too located"? Where does that verbiage come from? It looks like the original comment has been deleted so I can't see what they said if that was the verbiage they used.

Comment: @wjandrea: please check the edit history of the original meta post. This was in the title of the post when I wrote my answer. I'm just repeating what the OP stated, even if it didn't make sense, and hence the quotes.

Comment: @Hovercraft Ah OK, seems like just a mistake then. I'm guessing OP isn't a native English speaker. I went ahead and removed it since it's distracting.