Should questions in the [faq] tag on Meta have "canonical links"?
I noticed in the revisions of Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question? that an attempt was made to add a "canonical link" to the question, apparently intended for copying and pasting into Stack Overflow comments to point at policy. E.g.:

Canonical link: [Please specify where you are stuck.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

This change was rolled back by a moderator, with an edit summary claiming that comments offering such a link will also be removed. Similarly, Why should I post complete errors? Why isn't the message itself enough? (which I have had to refer to very often) doesn't offer such a link (although no attempt was made to add one).
However, other FAQ entries, such as Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? and Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query? (which incidentally has an overly specific title) and Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?, do include such links.
I fail to see how these questions are substantially different. Much other discussion on Meta has established the value of having copy-and-paste "template" comments to save time and frustration (and therefore avoid Code of Conduct violations in the long run) for curators. Personally I think that including a link like this - even if we don't call it "canonical" - makes sense for every FAQ entry that is generally about the content of questions and/or answers, at a minimum.

I would assume it's specific to that comment, and not canonical links in general. It doesn't read like a useful comment, and just "Please specify where you are stuck" isn't particularly useful imo.

I concur with Zoe.  Based on my discussions with Cody, he and I have both spent a bunch of effort trying to stop commenters from trying to get askers to turn perfectly good how-to questions into less useful debugging questions.  Having a copy-paste "canonical comment" for that particular thing (especially, but not only, that specific phrasing) encourages that sort of thing, whereas something like "Please do not upload images of code/data/errors." is never going to be bad advice.

How about wording like"Please identify one specific thing to ask about, and ask explicitly - we don't provide generic "help" here? But I do want to ask about the meta-topic generally.

That would be a notable improvement on the previously proposed phrasing.  I wouldn't be opposed to that.  My only slight worried is that people would use it improperly on questions that set out a (sufficiently focused) task that they want to ask about, and then say something like "I can't figure out how to do this" (stating, rather than asking), but...also people already do that and I don't think this would make it notably worse.

Some questions can't be fixed and needs to be closed. The "can someone help me" questions are closable as "needs details or clarity", no needs for a comment, nor for a canonical link.

@ayhan From one of Cody's (now deleted) comments on that question: "The reason we keep removing that "comment example" is because it's a bad example. We do not want people to copy-paste that into the comment box. If you just post a bare link to this question in a comment, the comment will get flagged and removed. It's okay to link to this, but you need to actually do a little bit of work to explain yourself and provide meaningful guidance to the asker" - in other words, precisely what I said in my first comment

Sure, but a comment just saying "How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?" with a link isn't useful; same as the case shown in the question. Standalone, it doesn't offer any guidance. See also Ryan's first comment on here

@Sinatr just to make sure you understand: closure is reversible, by design; and fixable questions should also be closed. It only means that the person reporting the problem couldn't singlehandedly fix it - in particular, because fixing it requires OP's involvement. On the other hand, explaining in detail to OP why a question is being closed is often quite useful.

One difference I see between the canonical links on the three questions cited in the "other FAQ entries" paragraph and the one that was removed is that the trio of questions have canonical links that very closely (or exactly) reflect the title of the canonical question, whereas the reject one used completely different text.  Had the suggestion been "[Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)" or something very close to that, it might have been acceptable.  The name in the suggested canonical link did not approach that level of usefulness.
